# Fast Prime Number Generation in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp, primes

I've been working on solving [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems in Clojure to get better, and I've already run into prime number generation a couple of times. My problem is that it is just taking way too long. I was hoping someone could help me find an efficient way to do this in a Clojure-y way.

When I fist did this, I brute-forced it. That was easy to do. But calculating 10001 prime numbers took 2 minutes this way on a Xeon 2.33GHz, too long for the rules, and too long in general. Here was the algorithm:

```
(defn next-prime-slow
    "Find the next prime number, checking against our already existing list"
    ([sofar guess]
        (if (not-any? #(zero? (mod guess %)) sofar)
            guess                         ; Then we have a prime
            (recur sofar (+ guess 2)))))  ; Try again                               

(defn find-primes-slow
    "Finds prime numbers, slowly"
    ([]
        (find-primes-slow 10001 [2 3]))   ; How many we need, initial prime seeds
    ([needed sofar]
        (if (<= needed (count sofar))
            sofar                         ; Found enough, we're done
            (recur needed (concat sofar [(next-prime-slow sofar (last sofar))])))))
```

By replacing next-prime-slow with a newer routine that took some additional rules into account (like the 6n +/- 1 property) I was able to speed things up to about 70 seconds.

Next I tried making a sieve of Eratosthenes in pure Clojure. I don't think I got all the bugs out, but I gave up because it was simply way too slow (even worse than the above, I think).

```clj
(defn clean-sieve
    "Clean the sieve of what we know isn't prime based"
    [seeds-left sieve]
    (if (zero? (count seeds-left))
        sieve              ; Nothing left to filter the list against
        (recur
            (rest seeds-left)    ; The numbers we haven't checked against
            (filter #(> (mod % (first seeds-left)) 0) sieve)))) ; Filter out multiples

(defn self-clean-sieve  ; This seems to be REALLY slow
    "Remove the stuff in the sieve that isn't prime based on it's self"
    ([sieve]
        (self-clean-sieve (rest sieve) (take 1 sieve)))
    ([sieve clean]
        (if (zero? (count sieve))
            clean
            (let [cleaned (filter #(> (mod % (last clean)) 0) sieve)]
                (recur (rest cleaned) (into clean [(first cleaned)]))))))

(defn find-primes
    "Finds prime numbers, hopefully faster"
    ([]
        (find-primes 10001 [2]))
    ([needed seeds]
        (if (>= (count seeds) needed)
            seeds        ; We have enough
            (recur       ; Recalculate
                needed
                (into
                    seeds    ; Stuff we've already found
                    (let [start (last seeds)
                            end-range (+ start 150000)]   ; NOTE HERE
                        (reverse                                                
                            (self-clean-sieve
                            (clean-sieve seeds (range (inc start) end-range))))))))))
```

This is bad. It also causes stack overflows if the number 150000 is smaller. This despite the fact I'm using recur. That may be my fault.

Next I tried a sieve, using Java methods on a Java ArrayList. That took quite a bit of time, and memory.

My latest attempt is a sieve using a Clojure hash-map, inserting all the numbers in the sieve then dissoc'ing numbers that aren't prime. At the end, it takes the key list, which are the prime numbers it found. It takes about 10-12 seconds to find 10000 prime numbers. I'm not sure it's fully debugged yet. It's recursive too (using recur and loop), since I'm trying to be Lispy.

So with these kind of problems, problem 10 (sum up all primes under 2000000) is killing me. My fastest code came up with the right answer, but it took 105 seconds to do it, and needed quite a bit of memory (I gave it 512 MB just so I wouldn't have to fuss with it). My other algorithms take so long I always ended up stopping them first.

I could use a sieve to calculate that many primes in Java or C quite fast and without using so much memory. I know I must be missing something in my Clojure/Lisp style that's causing the problem.

Is there something I'm doing really wrong? Is Clojure just kinda slow with large sequences? Reading some of the project Euler discussions people have calculated the first 10000 primes in other Lisps in under 100 miliseconds. I realize the JVM may slow things down and Clojure is relatively young, but I wouldn't expect a 100x difference.

Can someone enlighten me on a fast way to calculate prime numbers in Clojure?

Comment: Are you trying to generate lots of primes, large primes?  Test primality? What's the goal?

Comment: I was looking for a general algorithm. Partly this is just to improve my understanding of the language. One problem asked for the 10001st prime, one for the sum of all under 2000000. I expect there will be more. My algorithms above are all targeted at generating primes in order.

Comment: Not an answer, but something I found interesting ... http://bigdingus.com/2008/07/01/finding-primes-with-erlang-and-clojure/

Comment: I had the same problem with Project Euler and Haskell, though not of the same magnitude.  I'd implement the same algorithm in C and Haskell, and the C program would take a half second whereas Haskell took thirty.  This is mostly due to the fact that I don't really know how to add strictness to Haskell, as some algorithms take about equal times in both languages.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm running into. Some thing I've done (involving tons of multiplication and addition and other things) run blindingly fast. But this is horribly slow. I'm trying to learn what causes that so I can fix it or avoid it.

Comment: Check Alex Martelli's Python version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python
The difference is that one would not know how many numbers will be asked for in advance.

Answer (score 29):

Here's another approach that celebrates `Clojure's Java interop`. This takes 374ms on a 2.4 Ghz Core 2 Duo (running single-threaded). I let the efficient `Miller-Rabin` implementation in Java's `BigInteger#isProbablePrime` deal with the primality check.

```
(def certainty 5)

(defn prime? [n]
      (.isProbablePrime (BigInteger/valueOf n) certainty))

(concat [2] (take 10001 
   (filter prime? 
      (take-nth 2 
         (range 1 Integer/MAX_VALUE)))))
```

The `Miller-Rabin` certainty of 5 is probably not very good for numbers much larger than this. That certainty is equal to `96.875%` certain it's prime (`1 - .5^certainty`)

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know BigInteger.isProbablePrime existed.

Comment: 1 is not prime, BigInteger/isProbablePrime is right about that!

Answer (score 22):

I realize this is a very old question, but I recently ended up looking for the same and the links here weren't what I'm looking for (restricted to functional types as much as possible, lazily generating ~every~ prime I want).

I stumbled upon a nice [F# implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150710134640/http://diditwith.net/2009/01/20/YAPESProblemSevenPart2.aspx), so all credits are his. I merely ported it to Clojure:

```clj
(defn gen-primes "Generates an infinite, lazy sequence of prime numbers"
  []
  (letfn [(reinsert [table x prime]
             (update-in table [(+ prime x)] conj prime))
          (primes-step [table d]
             (if-let [factors (get table d)]
               (recur (reduce #(reinsert %1 d %2) (dissoc table d) factors)
                      (inc d))
               (lazy-seq (cons d (primes-step (assoc table (* d d) (list d))
                                              (inc d))))))]
    (primes-step {} 2)))
```

Usage is simply

```
(take 5 (gen-primes))
```

Comment: The linked article about the original F# implementation is excellent! This taught me a lot about maps in Clojure. Thanks!

Comment: Clojure does not recognize local function definitions like Scheme. `defn` is always global. For mutually-recursive local functions as in this example, use `letfn`.

Comment: The linked to F# article is gone. Here's the [archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150710134640/http://diditwith.net/2009/01/20/YAPESProblemSevenPart2.aspx)

Comment: I prefer this as a `def`. Here's my tweaked version:

`(def primes
  "Infinite, lazy sequence of prime numbers."
  ((fn step [m n]
     (or (some-> (get m n)
           (-> (->> (reduce #(update %1 (+ %2 n) conj %2) (dissoc m n)))
               (step (inc n))))
         (-> (assoc m (* n n) (list n))
             (step (inc n))
             (->> (cons n) (lazy-seq)))))
   {} 2))`

Key points:
- `m` for map, `n` for number
- Inlined `reinsert`
- `((fn name [args] ...) args)` pattern
- Illustrates the symmetry of the recursion cases by visually isolating `(step (inc n))`

Comment: @ASammich I've updated the link in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to terminate for me

Comment: @RaymondMachira It's a lazy, infinite sequence, so yeah, it won't terminate.  You have to do something with the result, like `(take 5 l)` or `(nth l 50)`

Comment: This is VERY old by now, but still wanted to say thanks for the post as it helped me understand the algorithm better after having read the paper on it. I did my own version which is similar to yours and it helped my understand some things with lazy sequences that have proved invaluable.

Comment: `(update-in table [(+ prime x)] conj prime)` is just `(update table (+ prime x) conj prime)`. You could also use a [transient](https://clojure.org/reference/transients) map to speed it up a bit (untested).

Answer (score 12):

Very late to the party, but I'll throw in an example, using Java BitSets:

```
(defn sieve [n]
  "Returns a BitSet with bits set for each prime up to n"
  (let [bs (new java.util.BitSet n)]
    (.flip bs 2 n)
    (doseq [i (range 4 n 2)] (.clear bs i))
    (doseq [p (range 3 (Math/sqrt n))]
      (if (.get bs p)
        (doseq [q (range (* p p) n (* 2 p))] (.clear bs q))))
    bs))
```

Running this on a 2014 Macbook Pro (2.3GHz Core i7), I get:

```
user=> (time (do (sieve 1e6) nil))
"Elapsed time: 64.936 msecs"
```

Comment: nice but how do you get from the bitset back to numbers?

Comment: This is a nice answer and very fast.  Oh, to get back to numbers you can do this `(take-while #(not (= % -1)) (iterate #(.nextSetBit theBitSet (inc %)) 2))`.

Answer (score 11):

See the last example here:
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq

```clj
;; An example combining lazy sequences with higher order functions
;; Generate prime numbers using Eratosthenes Sieve
;; See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes
;; Note that the starting set of sieved numbers should be
;; the set of integers starting with 2 i.e., (iterate inc 2) 
(defn sieve [s]
  (cons (first s)
        (lazy-seq (sieve (filter #(not= 0 (mod % (first s)))
                                 (rest s))))))

user=> (take 20 (sieve (iterate inc 2)))
(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71)
```

Comment: While this works for small numbers, even this method seems susceptible to StackOverflowError - I get them around the 2000th element or so

Comment: this is actually the *non-postponed sieve of Turner* (i.e. trial division sieve), not Eratosthenes. it's quadratic, while [the postponed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871918/849891) is about ~n^1.5 (in *n* primes produced)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice and simple implementation:

http://clj-me.blogspot.com/2008/06/primes.html

... but it is written for some pre-1.0 version of Clojure. See [lazy_seqs](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/lazy_seqs.clj) in Clojure Contrib for one that works with the current version of the language.

Comment: (side note:) the linked blog's clojure code amounts to `primes = 2 : filter (\n -> all ((> 0).rem n) $ takeWhile ((<= n) . (^2)) primes ) [3..]` in Haskell, the optimal trial division.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn sieve
  [[p & rst]]
  ;; make sure the stack size is sufficiently large!
  (lazy-seq (cons p (sieve (remove #(= 0 (mod % p)) rst)))))

(def primes (sieve (iterate inc 2)))
```

with a 10M stack size, I get the 1001th prime in ~ 33 seconds on a 2.1Gz macbook.

Comment: I got a stack overflow looking for the 100,000th prime

Comment: Every prime is checked for division by every prime less than it.  That's far worse than trial division, which only checks up to the square root.  The true sieve of Eratosthenes requires a data structure with fast random access lookup.  See http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 3):

So I've just started with Clojure, and yeah, this comes up a lot on Project Euler doesn't it? I wrote a pretty fast trial division prime algorithm, but it doesn't really scale too far before each run of divisions becomes prohibitively slow.

So I started again, this time using the sieve method:

```
(defn clense
  "Walks through the sieve and nils out multiples of step"
  [primes step i]
  (if (<= i (count primes))
    (recur 
      (assoc! primes i nil)
      step
      (+ i step))
    primes))

(defn sieve-step
  "Only works if i is >= 3"
  [primes i]
  (if (< i (count primes))
    (recur
      (if (nil? (primes i)) primes (clense primes (* 2 i) (* i i)))
      (+ 2 i))
    primes))

(defn prime-sieve
  "Returns a lazy list of all primes smaller than x"
  [x]
  (drop 2 
    (filter (complement nil?)
    (persistent! (sieve-step 
      (clense (transient (vec (range x))) 2 4) 3)))))
```

Usage and speed:

```
user=> (time (do (prime-sieve 1E6) nil))
"Elapsed time: 930.881 msecs
```

I'm pretty happy with the speed: it's running out of a REPL running on a 2009 MBP. It's mostly fast because I completely eschew idiomatic Clojure and instead loop around like a monkey. It's also 4X faster because I'm using a transient vector to work on the sieve instead of staying completely immutable.

**Edit:** After a couple of suggestions / bug fixes from Will Ness it now runs a whole lot faster.

Comment: in your `sieve-step`, you shouldn't call `clense-the-sieve` for `i` if `primes` at index `i` is already `nil`. `clense` should call itself as `(clense primes step (* step step))`. for `i > 2`, `sieve-step` can call directly `(clense primes (* 2 i) (* i i))`, and increment `i` by 2. :)

Comment: Oh whoops, I had that first suggestion in the code at some point, I guess too many rewrites..

Comment: So the last suggestion actually had it run slower. I'm still not really down with Clojure optimisation, but I'm guessing it's because I was lazy and had it do the (= 2 i) check each time, when really I should have split that whole thing off into unique code for that first call.

Comment: probably. :) you can have at least 2x speedup when going fully to work on odds only: i=i+2; step=2*i.

Comment: OK, *now* I'm going to leave this alone, it's fast enough ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple sieve in Scheme:

http://telegraphics.com.au/svn/puzzles/trunk/programming-in-scheme/primes-up-to.scm

Here's a run for primes up to 10,000:

```
#;1> (include "primes-up-to.scm")
; including primes-up-to.scm ...
#;2> ,t (primes-up-to 10000)
0.238s CPU time, 0.062s GC time (major), 180013 mutations, 130/4758 GCs (major/minor)
(2 3 5 7 11 13...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Clojure solution. `i` is the current number being considered and `p` is a list of all prime numbers found so far. If division by `some` prime numbers has a remainder of zero, the number `i` is not a prime number and recursion occurs with the next number. Otherwise the prime number is added to `p` in the next recursion (as well as continuing with the next number).

```
(defn primes [i p]
  (if (some #(zero? (mod i %)) p)
    (recur (inc i) p)
    (cons i (lazy-seq (primes (inc i) (conj p i))))))
(time (do (doall (take 5001 (primes 2 []))) nil))
; Elapsed time: 2004.75587 msecs
(time (do (doall (take 10001 (primes 2 []))) nil))
; Elapsed time: 7700.675118 msecs
```

Update:
Here is a much slicker solution based on [this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53231994/382784).
Basically the list of integers starting with two is filtered lazily. Filtering is performed by only accepting a number `i` if there is no prime number dividing the number with remainder of zero. All prime numbers are tried where the square of the prime number is less or equal to `i`.
Note that `primes` is used recursively but Clojure manages to prevent endless recursion. Also note that the lazy sequence `primes` caches results (that's why the performance results are a bit counter intuitive at first sight).

```
(def primes
  (lazy-seq
    (filter (fn [i] (not-any? #(zero? (rem i %))
                              (take-while #(<= (* % %) i) primes)))
            (drop 2 (range)))))
(time (first (drop 10000 primes)))
; Elapsed time: 542.204211 msecs
(time (first (drop 20000 primes)))
; Elapsed time: 786.667644 msecs
(time (first (drop 40000 primes)))
; Elapsed time: 1780.15807 msecs
(time (first (drop 40000 primes)))
; Elapsed time: 8.415643 msecs
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: [*Empirical orders of growth, **please!***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)

Comment: my guess is quadratic, i.e. 5000 primes takes about 810 msecs, is this about right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Will's comment, here is my take on [`postponed-primes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891):

```
(defn postponed-primes-recursive
  ([]
     (concat (list 2 3 5 7)
             (lazy-seq (postponed-primes-recursive
                        {}
                        3
                        9
                        (rest (rest (postponed-primes-recursive)))
                        9))))
  ([D p q ps c]
     (letfn [(add-composites
               [D x s]
               (loop [a x]
                 (if (contains? D a)
                   (recur (+ a s))
                   (persistent! (assoc! (transient D) a s)))))]
       (loop [D D
              p p
              q q
              ps ps
              c c]
         (if (not (contains? D c))
           (if (< c q)
             (cons c (lazy-seq (postponed-primes-recursive D p q ps (+ 2 c))))
             (recur (add-composites D
                                    (+ c (* 2 p))
                                    (* 2 p))
                    (first ps)
                    (* (first ps) (first ps))
                    (rest ps)
                    (+ c 2)))
           (let [s (get D c)]
             (recur (add-composites
                     (persistent! (dissoc! (transient D) c))
                     (+ c s)
                     s)
                    p
                    q
                    ps
                    (+ c 2))))))))
```

*Initial submission for comparison:*

Here is my attempt to port [this prime number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/568618) from Python to Clojure. The below returns an infinite lazy sequence.

```
(defn primes
  []
  (letfn [(prime-help
            [foo bar]
            (loop [D foo
                   q bar]
              (if (nil? (get D q))
                (cons q (lazy-seq
                         (prime-help
                          (persistent! (assoc! (transient D) (* q q) (list q)))
                          (inc q))))
                (let [factors-of-q (get D q)
                      key-val (interleave
                               (map #(+ % q) factors-of-q)
                               (map #(cons % (get D (+ % q) (list)))
                                    factors-of-q))]
                  (recur (persistent!
                          (dissoc!
                           (apply assoc! (transient D) key-val)
                           q))
                         (inc q))))))]
    (prime-help {} 2)))
```

Usage:

```
user=> (first (primes))
2
user=> (second (primes))
3
user=> (nth (primes) 100)
547
user=> (take 5 (primes))
(2 3 5 7 11)
user=> (time (nth (primes) 10000))
"Elapsed time: 409.052221 msecs"
104743
```

*edit:*

Performance comparison, where `postponed-primes` uses a queue of primes seen so far rather than a recursive call to `postponed-primes`:

```
user=> (def counts (list 200000 400000 600000 800000))
#'user/counts
user=> (map #(time (nth (postponed-primes) %)) counts)
("Elapsed time: 1822.882 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 3985.299 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 6916.98 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 8710.791 msecs"
2750161 5800139 8960467 12195263)
user=> (map #(time (nth (postponed-primes-recursive) %)) counts)
("Elapsed time: 1776.843 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 3874.125 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 6092.79 msecs"
 "Elapsed time: 8453.017 msecs"
2750161 5800139 8960467 12195263)
```

Comment: nice! I've edited to add the link. :) In Python the gain is much smaller; in your code the gain is very significant. Might be interesting to compare the [empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) too, between the two versions, plain and postponed.

Comment: I'd pass `q` as one more argument to `prime-helper`, not to recalculate it all the time. Another thing to try is to allow multiplicity in the dictionary: { 45:[6,10] } kind of thing. Interesting, what might be the effect of that. The code will have to be more involved, but would that be worth it?

Comment: (cf. this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625207/849891. how does your code fare in comparison?)

Comment: One difference between my postponed-primes and the one that you linked to is that, instead of using a "separate Primes Supply" `ps = (p for p in postponed_sieve())`, I'm initializing `ps` to a PersistentQueue with values 5 and 7, then pushing on primes as I see them with `(conj ps c)`.

Comment: `user=> (time (nth (gen-primes) 10000))
"Elapsed time: 539.591 msecs"
104743`

Comment: so your `postponed-primes` postpones adding the primes into dictionary (correctly) but it does needlessly add each prime to the tail of auxiliary list (queue). There should be a way to reuse a second invocation of the same function, `(postponed-primes)`, instead of using your PersistentQueue: `(prime-help {} 3 (postponed-primes) 9)`... (is this possible? advantageous? still interesting? :) :) )

Comment: (also, if you could give times for the three functions also at 75,000, 50,000 and 25,000, it would enable us to compare them *algorithmically*)

Comment: I wrote it that way assuming that the second invocation of the `prime-help` function would needlessly force a recalculation of primes (and also assumed that the second call to `prime-help` would cause another call to `prime-help` and so on). Is there some sort of automatic memoization or other thing going on?

Comment: I don't know Clojure to answer this. In Python, what works is a generator, maintaining its internal state, producing numbers one by one. First few primes (2,3,5,7) are specified inside. Each generator above, needs primes only up to the square root of its current production point, from the generator below. So the chain is finite and short enough.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's a tradeoff between the recursive call to the generator and the queue. The queue stores (worst case) all the primes between `p` and `p^2` but has constant time enqueuing and dequeuing operations. The recursive calls to the generator generate primes from 2 up to `c^.5`, which I guess tapers off quite quickly. After reconsideration, I think I'd rather take the recursive call approach.

Comment: Ok, so from further testing, the performance difference between the recursive call and the queue seems to be pretty marginal. Queue seems to be a little faster for smaller numbers of primes (maybe the first 500,000 primes) while the recursive call probably gets the edge as you go past that. Or maybe my machine happened to be doing something else while running some of those tests.

Comment: are you sure it should be `(if (< c q) (cons c (lazy-seq (prime-help D p ...` and not `(if (< c q) (lazy-seq (cons c (prime-help D p ...`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7625207/849891 seems to be doing the latter. Maybe that's why its `gen-primes` is a little bit faster than your `primes`. -- With the new data we see that the empirical orders of growth for both primes and gen-primes are around n^1.25 (at the tested range), for postponed with queue - n^1.11..1.16 and with recursive call - n^1.05..1.15. Of course the numbers are approximate, but the general picture can be seen there.

Comment: I think I have the `lazy-seq` in the right place. See, e.g., http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/lazy_DASH_seq/.

Comment: Also, you were right about adding `q` as an argument to prime-help. Avoiding those unnecessary multiplications makes it about 20% faster.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic, and not too bad

```clj
(def primes
  (cons 1 (lazy-seq
            (filter (fn [i]
                      (not-any? (fn [p] (zero? (rem i p)))
                                (take-while #(<= % (Math/sqrt i))
                                            (rest primes))))
                    (drop 2 (range))))))
=> #'user/primes
(first (time (drop 10000 primes)))
"Elapsed time: 0.023135 msecs"
=> 104729
```

Comment: You need to run `(time (first (drop 10000 primes)))`.

Comment: Upvoted though because it is really nice idiomatic code.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://steloflute.tistory.com/entry/Clojure-%ED%94%84%EB%A1%9C%EA%B7%B8%EB%9E%A8-%EC%B5%9C%EC%A0%81%ED%99%94

Using Java array

```
(defmacro loopwhile [init-symbol init whilep step & body]
  `(loop [~init-symbol ~init]
     (when ~whilep ~@body (recur (+ ~init-symbol ~step)))))

(defn primesUnderb [limit]
  (let [p (boolean-array limit true)]
    (loopwhile i 2 (< i (Math/sqrt limit)) 1
               (when (aget p i)
                 (loopwhile j (* i 2) (< j limit) i (aset p j false))))
    (filter #(aget p %) (range 2 limit))))
```

Usage and speed:

```
user=> (time (def p (primesUnderb 1e6)))
"Elapsed time: 104.065891 msecs"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Clojure so I don't know if it's good but here is my solution:

```clj
(defn divides? [x i]
  (zero? (mod x i)))

(defn factors [x]
    (flatten (map #(list % (/ x %)) 
                 (filter #(divides? x %) 
                        (range 1 (inc (Math/floor (Math/sqrt x))))))))

(defn prime? [x]
  (empty? (filter #(and divides? (not= x %) (not= 1 %)) 
                 (factors x))))

(def primes 
  (filter prime? (range 2 java.lang.Integer/MAX_VALUE)))

(defn sum-of-primes-below [n]
  (reduce + (take-while #(< % n) primes)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After coming to this thread and searching for a faster alternative to those already here, I am surprised nobody linked to the following [article by Christophe Grand](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/07/30/everybody-loves-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes/) :

```
(defn primes3 [max]
  (let [enqueue (fn [sieve n factor]
                  (let [m (+ n (+ factor factor))]
                    (if (sieve m)
                      (recur sieve m factor)
                      (assoc sieve m factor))))
        next-sieve (fn [sieve candidate]
                     (if-let [factor (sieve candidate)]
                       (-> sieve
                         (dissoc candidate)
                         (enqueue candidate factor))
                       (enqueue sieve candidate candidate)))]
    (cons 2 (vals (reduce next-sieve {} (range 3 max 2))))))
```

As well as a lazy version :

```
(defn lazy-primes3 []
  (letfn [(enqueue [sieve n step]
            (let [m (+ n step)]
              (if (sieve m)
                (recur sieve m step)
                (assoc sieve m step))))
          (next-sieve [sieve candidate]
            (if-let [step (sieve candidate)]
              (-> sieve
                (dissoc candidate)
                (enqueue candidate step))
              (enqueue sieve candidate (+ candidate candidate))))
          (next-primes [sieve candidate]
            (if (sieve candidate)
              (recur (next-sieve sieve candidate) (+ candidate 2))
              (cons candidate 
                (lazy-seq (next-primes (next-sieve sieve candidate) 
                            (+ candidate 2))))))]
    (cons 2 (lazy-seq (next-primes {} 3)))))
```

Comment: `(enqueue sieve candidate candidate)` can be safely replaced with `(enqueue sieve (- (* candidate candidate) candidate candidate) candidate)`. this will entail [change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891) that will bring memory requirements down  from O(n) to O(sqrt(n)), and depending on how good the dictionary implementation in Clojure is, could even give a sizeable constant factor (or even slight algorithmic (i.e. empirical orders of growth) improvement). coincidentally, the linked answer links to 2002(?) Python recipe which is an exact equivalent of this one in your answer. :)

Comment: (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+postponed+sieve)

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of answers already, but I have an alternative solution which generates an infinite sequence of primes. I was also interested on bechmarking a few solutions.

First some Java interop. for reference:

```
(defn prime-fn-1 [accuracy]
  (cons 2
    (for [i (range)
          :let [prime-candidate (-> i (* 2) (+ 3))]
          :when (.isProbablePrime (BigInteger/valueOf prime-candidate) accuracy)]
      prime-candidate)))
```

Benjamin @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625207/3731823 is `primes-fn-2`

nha @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/36432061/3731823 is `primes-fn-3`

My implementations is `primes-fn-4`:

```
(defn primes-fn-4 []
  (let [primes-with-duplicates
         (->> (for [i (range)] (-> i (* 2) (+ 5))) ; 5, 7, 9, 11, ...
              (reductions
                (fn [known-primes candidate]
                  (if (->> known-primes
                           (take-while #(<= (* % %) candidate))
                           (not-any?   #(-> candidate (mod %) zero?)))
                   (conj known-primes candidate)
                   known-primes))
                [3])     ; Our initial list of known odd primes
              (cons [2]) ; Put in the non-odd one
              (map (comp first rseq)))] ; O(1) lookup of the last element of the vec "known-primes"

    ; Ugh, ugly de-duplication :(
    (->> (map #(when (not= % %2) %) primes-with-duplicates (rest primes-with-duplicates))
         (remove nil?))))
```

Reported numbers (time in milliseconds to count first N primes) are the fastest from the run of 5, no JVM restarts between experiments so your mileage may vary:

```
                     1e6      3e6

(primes-fn-1  5)     808     2664
(primes-fn-1 10)     952     3198
(primes-fn-1 20)    1440     4742
(primes-fn-1 30)    1881     6030
(primes-fn-2)       1868     5922
(primes-fn-3)        489     1755  <-- WOW!
(primes-fn-4)       2024     8185
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a lazy solution and you just want a sequence of primes below a certain limit, the straight forward implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is pretty fast.  Here's my version using transients:

```
(defn classic-sieve
  "Returns sequence of primes less than N"
  [n]
  (loop [nums (transient (vec (range n))) i 2]
    (cond
     (> (* i i) n) (remove nil? (nnext (persistent! nums)))
     (nums i) (recur (loop [nums nums j (* i i)]
                       (if (< j n)
                         (recur (assoc! nums j nil) (+ j i))
                         nums))
                     (inc i))
     :else (recur nums (inc i)))))
```