# Lazy List of Prime Numbers

Tags: list, haskell, primes, lazy-evaluation

How would one implement a list of prime numbers in Haskell so that they could be retrieved lazily?

I am new to Haskell, and would like to learn about practical uses of the lazy evaluation functionality.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764163/help-explain-this-chunk-of-haskell-code-that-outputs-a-stream-of-primes?

Comment: Consider http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes

Comment: Quite the contrary: it's a tricky task to create non-lazy prime numbers list in Haskell

Comment: [by walpen at codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6316/5021): `nubBy (((==0).).rem) [2..]`. To try it out in GHCi first bring up the `Data.List` module with `Prelude> :m +Data.List`. But lazyness plays no role here, except allowing for the *unbounded* definition. `[2..10000]` could be used as well and evaluated strictly.

Comment: @WillNess; that yields all numbers here. Maybe you meant `nubBy (((>1).).gcd) [2..]`?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner yes; the former code was working on older versions of GHC (it works e.g. on 7.8.3). The newer ones flipped the order of arguments to the nubBy's function, IIRC. or is it the other way around and you're on an *older* version? (because the code with `rem` also works fine on tryhaskell.org).

Comment: I’m on GHC-7.10 right now. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33533257/946226 for a rationale of the change.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner so it was working on the *older* versions (though shouldn't have). OK.

Comment: FWIW, it *is* possible to [find one *n*th prime directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704912/849891), independently of all the previous ones. (see **"The fast way"** section in that answer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a short Haskell function that enumerates primes from [Literate Programs:](https://web.archive.org/web/20100710032905/http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_%28Haskell%29)

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve [2..]
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

Apparently, this is *not* the Sieve of Eratosthenes (thanks, Landei). I think it's still an instructive example that shows you can write very elegant, short code in Haskell and that shows how the choice of the wrong data structure can badly hurt efficiency.

Comment: Please read this and rethink your answer:

http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: The "wrong data structure" (i.e. list) has nothing to do with that code's *extreme* inefficiency ( O(n^2), *in `n` primes produced* ), which is instead the result of premature firing up of filters on each newly found prime instead of on its *square*. With filters creation [correctly postponed](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Postponed_Filters), it instead runs at about O(n^1.4..1.45) (in `n` primes produced), just like any other normal trial division.

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of solutions for lazy generation of prime sequences right in the haskell wiki. The first and simplest is the [Postponed Turner sieve](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/index.php?title=Prime_numbers&oldid=36858#Postponed_Filters_Sieve): <sup>(old revision ... NB)</sup>

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2: 3: sieve (tail primes) [5,7..]
 where 
  sieve (p:ps) xs = h ++ sieve ps [x | x <- t, x `rem` p /= 0]  
                                -- or:  filter ((/=0).(`rem`p)) t
                  where (h,~(_:t)) = span (< p*p) xs
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer from @nikie is not very efficient, is gets relatively slow after some thousands, but the answer of @sleepynate is much better. It took me some time to understand it, therefore here is the same code, but just with variables named more clearly:

```
lazyPrimes :: [Integer]
lazyPrimes = 2: 3: calcNextPrimes (tail lazyPrimes) [5, 7 .. ]
  where
    calcNextPrimes (p:ps) candidates =
      let (smallerSquareP, (_:biggerSquareP)) = span (< p * p) candidates in
      smallerSquareP ++ calcNextPrimes ps [c | c <- biggerSquareP, rem c p /= 0]
```

The main idea is that the candidates for the next primes already contain no numbers that are divisible by any prime less than the first prime given to the function. So that if you call

```
calcNextPrimes (5:ps) [11,13,17..]
```

the candidate list contains no number, that is divisible by `2` or `3`, that means that the first non-prime candidate will be `5 * 5`, cause  `5* 2` and `5 * 3` and `5 * 4` are already eliminated. That allows you to take all candidates, that are smaller than the square of 5 and add them straight away to the primes and sieve the rest to eliminate all numbers divisible by 5.

Answer (score 3):

```
primes = 2 : [x | x <- [3..], all (\y -> x `mod` y /= 0) 
                   (takeWhile (<= (floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral x)) primes)]
```

With *2* in the list initially, for each integer *`x`* greater than *2*, check if for all *`y`* in *`primes`* such that *`y <= sqrt(x)`*, *`x mod y != 0`* holds, which means *`x`* has no other factors except *1* and itself.

Comment: You might want to use `[3,5..]` instead of `[3..]`

Comment: you might also want to use ````(\n -> n*n <= x)```` or ````((<= n) . (^2))````instead of ````(<= (floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral x)````

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep things separate so that one might come in and ask: "is 1 a (unary) prime number?" ('unary' in the sense that it only needs itself to pass the primality test).

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2 : 3 : potentialPrimes
```

Should the community's answer be 'yes', then the above code can start with 1, because the other prime numbers are going to be generated by the `potentialPrimes` call.

```
potentialPrimes :: [Integer]
potentialPrimes = 5 : 7 : [p | p <- [6*k+l | k <- [1..], l <- [5,7]], isPrime p]
```

What it does is to consider 5 and 7 as given, and then generate multiples of the perfect number 6 - its divisors, excluding 6 itself, sum up to it - with 5 or 7 added for potential twin primes. They're going to be checked by `isPrime` at every `p`.

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = all (\p -> n `mod` p /= 0) (takeWhile (\p -> p*p <= n) potentialPrimes)
```

And last, but not the least, what this does is to consider if every number that has been fetched from the potential primes list, whose square is less than or equal to the one we're testing, satisfies the condition that they do not divide the tested number. It's true when none of them divide it (hence `all`), so `p` can be added to the primes' list, when a single exception makes it false and excludes the number.