# Get sqrt from Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, sqrt

How can I get `sqrt` from `Int`.

I try so:

```
sqrt . fromInteger x
```

But get error with types compatibility.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using `fromIntegral`:

```
Prelude> let x = 5::Int
Prelude> sqrt (fromIntegral  x)
2.23606797749979
```

both `Int` and `Integer` are instances of `Integral`:

- `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` takes your `Int` (which is an instance of `Integral`) and "makes" it a `Num`.
- `sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a` expects a `Floating`, and `Floating` inherit from `Fractional`, which inherits from `Num`, so you can safely pass to `sqrt` the result of `fromIntegral`

I think that the classes [diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:HaskellClasses.svg) in [Haskell Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Class_declarations) is quite useful in this cases.

Comment: Could `sqrt (fromIntegral  x)` also be written as `sqrt $ fromIntegral  x`?

Comment: Yes indeed it could, since explicit application ($) does not bind as tightly as implicit application.

Comment: or even `sqrt . fromIntegral $ x`

Comment: I prefer to write it as `((((($)))((sqrt))(fromIntegral (x))))`.

Answer (score 54):

Perhaps you want the result to be an `Int` as well?

```haskell
isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral
```

You may want to replace `floor` with `ceiling` or `round`.
(BTW, this function has a more general type than the one I gave.)

Comment: ghc warns about this, since it doesn't know which exact type to use between `fromIntegral` and `floor` (could be `Double`,`Float`, etc.). To fix: `isqrt x = floor . sqrt $ (fromIntegral x :: Float)`, which is less elegant :(

Comment: I like it, anyway. No warns on GHC 8.

Comment: ghc will warn if `-Wtype-defaults, -Werror=type-defaults`.

Answer (score 13):

Remember, application binds more tightly than any other operator. That includes composition. What you want is

```
sqrt $ fromIntegral x
```

Then

```
fromIntegral x
```

will be evaluated first, because implicit application (space) binds more tightly than explicit application ($).

Alternately, if you want to see how composition would work:

```
(sqrt .  fromIntegral) x
```

Parentheses make sure that the composition operator is evaluated first, and then the resulting function is the left side of the application.