# Function that tells if a number ir prime or not

Tags: haskell

``
I'm a Haskell newbie and I'm defining a function that given an Int n it tells if a number is prime or not by searching for an 2<=m<=sqrt(n) that mod n m ==0
if such m exists, then n is not prime, if not then n is prime.
I'm trying to define a list with numbers m between 2 and sqrt n, that mod n m ==0
My thought is that if the list is empty then n is prime, it not, n is not prime
`

```
isprime' :: Int -> Bool           
isprime' n | l == [] = True
           | otherwise = False

           where 
            l = [x|x<-[2.. sqrt n], mod n x == 0]
```

`

But there seems to be a problem with sqrt n when I run my code and I can't understand it. can someone explain what I'm doing wrong/what to change for my code to run/ and why there's an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the code gives the following error

```
test.hs:9:28: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    • In the expression: sqrt n
      In the expression: [2 .. sqrt n]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [2 .. sqrt n]
  |
9 |             l = [x|x<-[2.. sqrt n], mod n x == 0]
  |                            ^^^^^^
```

You are correct in saying that the error is with `sqrt`, but the rest is pretty opaque to a new Haskell developer. Lets try by checking the type of `sqrt` to see if that helps.

```
Prelude> :t sqrt
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

Here I'm using `ghci` to interactively write code. `:t` asks for the type of the preceeding expression. The line `sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a` says `sqrt` takes in some floating point number `a` and returns something of the same type.

Similar to our error message we see this `Floating` *thing*. this *thing* is a [typeclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) but for the sake of solving this problem we'll save understanding those for later. In essence, haskell is trying to tell you that `Int` is not floating point number which is what `sqrt` expects. We can amend that by turning our `Int` into a `Float` with `fromIntegral` which is a really general function for turning number types into one another. (see [Get sqrt from Int in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695267/get-sqrt-from-int-in-haskell))

```
isprime' :: Int -> Bool           
isprime' n | l == [] = True
           | otherwise = False
           where         
            asFloat :: Float -- new! - tell fromIntegral we want a float
            asFloat = fromIntegral n -- new! turn n into a Float
            l = [x|x<-[2..sqrt asFloat], mod n x == 0]
```

This also errors! but it's a new one!

```
test.hs:10:48: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Float’
    • In the second argument of ‘mod’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘mod n x’
      In the expression: mod n x == 0
   |
10 |             l = [x|x<-[2..sqrt asFloat], mod n x == 0]
   |                                                ^
```

this is saying that x is suddenly a `Float`. When we changed to `[2..sqrt asFloat]` we now have made a list of `Float`s (`[Float]`). We need to change that back to `[Int]`. we can do that by calling `floor` on the result of the square root.

```
isprime' :: Int -> Bool           
isprime' n | l == [] = True
           | otherwise = False
           where         
            asFloat :: Float
            asFloat = fromIntegral n 
            l = [x|x<-[2..floor (sqrt asFloat)], mod n x == 0] -- new! I added floor here to change the result of sqrt from a `Float` into a `Int`
```

This now correctly compiles.