# Haskell - parsing error on input

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskell and stuck with the input parse error on '='
I was trying a function to check if a number is prime
Here is the function -

```
isprime x
| x<=1 = "not prime"
| x == 2 = "yes"
| a = floor (sqrt x)
  lis = [2..a]
  divbylis (headlis:taillis)
    | length taillis <=0 = "yes it is prime"
    | x 'mod' headlis == 0 = "No not prime"
    | otherwise = divbylis taillis**
```

and it shows the error -

```
first.hs:58:15: error:
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

line 58 is the line with declaration of lis = [2..a]**

Comment: You write `a = floor (sqrt 5)`, which makes no sense since Haskell expects a guard.

Comment: Did you maybe mean to have a `where` block somewhere?

Comment: The `| a = floor (sqrt x)` line is weird - what's a? I think you meant to write a `where` at the end of that line, but that won't fix the problem you're having here.

Comment: Just using the common code of checking prime , creating a list of numbers from 2 to sqrt of the number and dividing by each of them

Comment: @jatin: but what you do is using *imperative style* code into a functional/declarative language. One of the ideas behind Haskell is to move away from that imperative approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some feedback:

- You posted some code and a syntax error, but you didn't ask a question. Presumably your question is *"Why doesn't this code work?"* but that's actually not a good question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- Your function is a predicate, but it returns a String. Consider returning a Bool instead.
- Give your function a type signature:

  ```
  isprime :: Int -> Bool
  isprime ...
  ```
- Your main syntax error is due to indentation; your guards are at the top-level. Write *at least* one space before the guards:

  ```
  isprime :: Int -> Bool
  isprime x
    | x <= 1 = False
    | x == 2 = True
    | ...
  ```
- Use pattern matching when appropriate:

  ```
  isprime :: Int -> Bool
  isprime 1 = False
  isprime 2 = True
  isprime n = ...
  ```
- I'm not *reaaally* sure what goes on at the "`lis = [2..a]`" and "`divbylis (headlis:taillis)`" part. It doesn't look like Haskell code. Is that supposed to be a helper function?
- If writing a prime function is too difficult, then try writing simpler numeric, recursive functions like `factorial`, `power`, `fibonacci`, `collatz`. If you want to see how others have done it, see: [Determining if a given number is a prime in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690762/determining-if-a-given-number-is-a-prime-in-haskell), [Is there a better way to write the isPrime function?](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2kg5br/is_there_a_better_way_to_write_the_isprime/)

Comment: Thanks,  headlis is just the first element of the list and taillis is the remaining list. My bad , it was my first question on stackoverflow and also thanks for your concerns