# find nth prime number

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, complexity-theory, primes

I've written the following code below to find the nth prime number. Can this be improved in time complexity?

Description:

The ArrayList arr stores the computed prime numbers. Once arr reaches a size 'n', the loop exits and we retrieve the nth element in the ArrayList. Numbers 2 and 3 are added before the prime numbers are calculated, and each number starting from 4 is checked to be prime or not.

```
public void calcPrime(int inp) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // stores prime numbers 
                                                      // calculated so far
    // add prime numbers 2 and 3 to prime array 'arr'
    arr.add(2); 
    arr.add(3);

    // check if number is prime starting from 4
    int counter = 4;
     // check if arr's size has reached inp which is 'n', if so terminate while loop
    while(arr.size() <= inp) {
        // dont check for prime if number is divisible by 2
        if(counter % 2 != 0) {
            // check if current number 'counter' is perfectly divisible from 
           // counter/2 to 3
            int temp = counter/2;
            while(temp >=3) {
                if(counter % temp == 0)
                    break;
                temp --;
            }
            if(temp <= 3) {
                arr.add(counter);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("finish" +arr.get(inp));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give us an intuitive description of what your program does, or at least provide comments.  Giving us a block of code and asking us to analyze it makes it extremely difficult for anyone to figure out what it means.

Comment: It may be open to question whether it improves the computational complexity, but a sieve of Eratosthenes is quite a bit *faster* anyway.

Comment: @templatetypedef: added comments to code.

Comment: The full answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704912/849891 .

Comment: Also, it is good to search the SO first: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/primes/hot?filter=year .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes.**

Your algorithm make **O(n^2)** operations (maybe I'm not accurate, but seems so),
where **n** is result.

There are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes algorithm that takes **O(ipn* log(log(n)))**. You can make only **inp** steps in it, and assume that **n = 2ipn*ln(ipn)**.
**n** just should be greater then **ipn**-prime.
(we know distributions of prime numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Anyway, you can improve existing solution:

```
public void calcPrime(int inp) {
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);

    int counter = 4;

    while(arr.size() < inp) {
        if(counter % 2 != 0 && counter%3 != 0) {
            int temp = 4;
            while(temp*temp <= counter) {
                if(counter % temp == 0)
                    break;
                temp ++;
            }
            if(temp*temp > counter) {
                arr.add(counter);
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("finish" +arr.get(inp-1));
    }
}
```

Comment: could you tell me how this works, specifically why do you check using temp*temp? thats going to check if the counter is divisible by 16,25,36..

Comment: He checks temp*temp against counter since that implies that temp <= sqrt(counter). It's enough to check up to that point since multiplication is commutative.

Comment: what is **n**? what is **ipn**? Is **inp**  `inp`? Is this the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: Don't you need to add 1 to arr?  Otherwise asking for the first prime number yields 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Keegan, prime numbers start from 2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Definition_and_examples

Answer (score 2):

A few things you can do to speed it up:

1. Start counter at 5 and increment it by 2 instead of 1, then don't check mod 2 in the loop.
2. Instead of starting temp at counter / 2, start it at the first odd <= int(sqrt(counter))
3. decrement temp by 2.

I'm not sure whether it counts as improving complexity, but (2) above will go from O(n^2) to O(n*sqrt(n))

Comment: testing by `temp` from the `sqrt` down is very inefficient. I suspect it even changes the complexity for the worse.

Comment: @Will It does indeed. I haven't analysed it in detail, but the semiprimes whose larger factor is at least four times the smaller factor alone give an additional `log log n` factor. I expect that the constant factor slowdown is much worse for a long long time, though.

Comment: @Daniel empirically ideone.com/iNxOrC indeed the counting-down code seems to run in `m^1.5`, where m is the top limit. The ratios of actual run times are `2.6x ... 3.6x` and worsening, for top limit 100k ... 1.2mln. `m^1.5` for counting-down code actually makes sense - there's no early cut-off so it's as if testing *each odd* by all odds below sqrt. While in counting-up the cost for non-prime odds is at the most the same as for primes (as shows M. O'Neill), giving the `m^1.5/log(m)`.

Comment: @Will What do you mean with "early cut-off"? You divide until you find the first divisor or hit the limit, whether you count up or down, in that respect, both ways are similar. Counting down, you generally have a much longer way to the first divisor, though. I sort-of expect it to be `Θ(√n)` on average (so the empirical `m^1.5` fits), but I don't see an easy way to prove it (closest divisor to `√n` is harder to grip than smallest prime divisor).

Comment: @Daniel that's what I meant, yes, the much longer way is almost "all the way". It is of course not rigorous in any way. Try finding the "expected value" of biggest factor for a randomly-chosen composite in the range 2..n, something to that effect (it will be our cut-off point, on average, counting down). `n` or `sqrt(n)`, I expect won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Daniel ouch. how stupid of me. of course it must be greatest factor of `i` below **`sqrt i`** for `i<-[2..n]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a Number : ");
        int num;
        int[] arr = new int[10000];
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int k;
        k = 0;
        int t = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= j; i++)
            {
                if (j % i == 0)
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if (k == 2)
            {
                arr[t] = j;
                t++;
                k = 0; 
            }
            else
            { 
                k = 0;
            } 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Nth Prime number. {0}", arr[num]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Can you include an indication of the improvement?

Comment: *How* does this `[improve] time complexity [of find the nth prime over counting primes identified by trial division]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println("Enter The number n: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = scanner.nextInt();

    int x = 0;
    String prime = "";

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

        int counter = 0;

        for (x = i; x >= 1; x--) {

            if (i % x == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        if (counter == 2){
            prime =  prime + i + " ";
        }

    }

    System.out.println(prime);
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).