# Python: Trouble testing primality of a number using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, primes, sieve

I am trying to calculate the nth prime using the Sieve of Eratosthenes. For large values of n though, it would speed up the process to generate some lower bound, and then only sieve the values above this lower bound until the nth prime was found. The lower bound that I am using here is `lower_bound = n * (ln + log(ln, e))`, where `ln = log(n, e)`. This provides a decent estimation for values of n >= 2. Then I would use the Sieve of Eratosthenes to sieve starting from this lower bound until the nth prime is found. I have implemented this fully using this code:

```
def find_nth_prime(n, lower=3):
    primes = [2]
    previous_primes = primepi(lower)
    candidate = lower
    while len(primes) < (n - previous_primes + 2):
        is_prime = True
        for prime in primes:
            if candidate % 5 == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
            if prime > ceil(sqrt(candidate + 1)):
                break
            if candidate % prime == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            primes.append(candidate)
        candidate += 2
    return primes[-1]
```

The problem with this code is that it does not test primality using the primes below this lower bound. For example, if I tried to do `find_nth_prime(10, 5)` it would output 23 (the 9th prime) because it thinks that 9 is prime because it does not test for divisibility by 3, because it is below the lower bound and thus not included in the numbers it tests divisibility with. I have tried calculating the primes up until the lower bound, and then using this as my primes list in `find_nth_prime`, but this defeats the purpose of having a lower bound in the first place. I can't just add the primes before because my goal is to use this function for fairly large values of n, so adding them in manually every time would be impractical. I also don't really want to import a list of primes because that also defeats the purpose and I could just use that list to find the nth prime. I have done some reading on other questions similar to this, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625663/calculating-and-printing-the-nth-prime-number), but the explanation given does not explain how to sieve from a lower bound, it just simply says to do it. The link given at the bottom of that answer also no longer works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `primepi()`?

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with your mathematical expectations. [math.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Barmar It is a function from sympy that counts the number of primes less than or equal to some number n. I am aware that this probably uses a pre-determined list of primes to find this, but I cannot find a decent explanation of the Meisser-Lehmer algorithm to implement it in python myself.

Comment: Your logic can't work. The Sieve of Eratosthenes requires you to start sieving at the beginning, and you've discovered this. There is no shortcut that lets you ignore earlier primes. You might examine the segmented sieve as an alternative.

Comment: Please, fix _all_ the imports, i.e. also for `ceil`, `sqrt`