# Map custom and arbitrary functions with sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, command-line

I'm trying to use commands `sed` or `awk`, together with arbitrary functions (or commands) defined, for example, as Bash scripts. **For example**, the following Bash script `prepend_largest_prime.sh` accepts a string as its first argument, and outputs the larger prime number below N, where N is the length of the string:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_prime() {
# Returns 1 if a number is prime, 0 if not
    i=2
    if [ $1 -lt 2 ]
    then
        return 0
    fi
    
    max=`echo "sqrt($1)" | bc`
    while [ $i -le $max ]
    do
        if [ `expr $1 % $i` -eq 0 ]
        then
            return 0
        fi
        i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    
    return 1
}

largest_prime_under() {
    counter=$1
    is_prime $counter 
    counter_primeQ=$?

    if [[ $counter_primeQ = 1 ]]; then
        echo $counter
        exit 1
    fi
    counter=$[ $counter - 1 ]

    while [[ $counter -gt 0 ]] ; do
        is_prime $counter
        counter_primeQ=$?
        if [[ $counter_primeQ = 1 ]]; then
            echo "$counter"
            exit 1
        fi
        counter=$[ $counter - 1 ]
    done
}

string_length() {
    str="$1"
    n=${#str}
    echo "$n"
}

string_length_num=$(string_length "$1")
largest_prime_under_string=$(largest_prime_under $string_length_num)

echo $largest_prime_under_string $1
```

An example call of this script could be:

```bash
$ ./prepend_largest_prime.sh 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
43 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Here the passed string has 44 characters, and the larger prime number below 44 is 43.

This is all I have managed to do. It still doesn't work and seems too complicated for the task at hand:

```bash
cat input_file.txt
The majestic mountains towered over the quaint little beautiful village below.
The serene garden is colorful.
The old oak trees stood tall, their branches reaching towards the sky.
```

```bash
$ sed "s|.*|\"\$(\./prepend_largest_prime.sh '&')\"|" input_file.txt
"$(./prepend_largest_prime.sh 'The majestic mountains towered over the quaint little beautiful village below.')"
"$(./prepend_largest_prime.sh 'The serene garden is colorful.')"
"$(./prepend_largest_prime.sh 'The old oak trees stood tall, their branches reaching towards the sky.')"
```

For this example, the output of the command I'm looking for should be

```
73 The majestic mountains towered over the quaint little beautiful village below.
29 The serene garden is colorful.
67 The old oak trees stood tall, their branches reaching towards the sky.
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `$[...]` or `expr`; just use `$((...))` for integer arithmetic.

Comment: Aside: Backticks for command substitution have been outdated since the early 90s standardized `$()`. Better to use `max=$(echo "sqrt($1)" | bc)`. Similarly, `$[ ]` is a legacy ksh syntax that has _never_ been standardized; the standard math syntax is `counter=$(( counter - 1 ))`, or the modern bashism is `(( counter-- ))`

Comment: And you're missing a lot of quotes -- https://shellcheck.net/ will catch those faults. And in general, branch directly on return status -- that is, `if is_prime someval; then`, not the more complicated and error-prone `is_prime someval; retval=$?; if [ "$retval" = 1 ]; then`

Comment: If you don't insist on `sed` or `awk`, a simple shell loop would suffice; `while IFS= read -r line; ./prepend_largest_prime.sh "$line"; done < input_file.txt`.

Comment: Ugh. Why do primes in Bash?!? This is really a job for Python, Perl, Ruby, or even awk. You are going down a rabbit hole of trying to fit a square peg in a round hole...

Comment: `is_prime() { openssl prime "$1" | grep -qv not; }`

Comment: Regarding awk I suggest taking look at [redirection to command](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preliminary: All of the following assumes that the data are presented one item per line, without embedded newlines, and that all characters between newlines are significant.

> I'm trying to use commands `sed` or `awk`, together with arbitrary functions (or commands) defined, for example, as Bash scripts.

That's awkward, no pun intended.  What you describe is better suited to the shell, as was described in comments.  Alternatively, `xargs` is designed expressly for converting input into arguments of commands, as you want to do:

```
xargs -d '\n' -n1 ./prepend_largest_prime.sh < input.txt
```

If you *must* drive it via `awk` or `sed` then you do have options. POSIX does not define a means by which `sed` can execute external commands, but if you can rely on extensions provided by GNU `sed` then its `e` command could serve.  You would edit the input line into the command you want to execute, then execute it with `e`:

```
sed "s,^\(.*\)\$,./prepend_largest_prime.sh '\1',; e" input.txt
```

There are other ways to work the details, but that particular approach uses an `s` command to wrap the input line in single quotes and prepend the name of the command to execute.  Note well that it will break if the input contains single quotes, though you could accommodate that with a bit more effort.

The `awk` version is more standard and a bit easier to read, using its `system()` function, but the idea is largely the same.  Edit each input line into the shell command you want to execute, and pass the result to `system()`:

```
awk '{ system("./doit.sh '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'") }' < input.txt
```

Like with the `sed`-based approach, you would need to do more work to accommodate inputs containing single-quote characters.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Thanks also for pointing out that the proper command for what I want to do is actually `xargs`. I didn't know it. Just one thing, the `awk` command you posted is not working as expected, it just returns the string "3 bash" three times, in separated lines. And I'm sorry for the rudimentary and full of gotchas script example I posted. I meant it only as an example of an "arbitrary function".

Comment: @gambarimas87, my bad on the `awk` command.  The original version used incorrect quoting.  I have replaced it with a corrected (but necessarily uglier) version.

Comment: `system("./doit.sh '"'"'" $0 "'"'"'")` = `system("./doit.sh \047" $0 "\047")` which IMO is a bit easier on the eyes. Starting a new subshell to call `doit.sh` once per input line would be a pretty slow process though since awk isn't designed to sequence calls to other tools (that's what a shell is for).

Answer (score 3):

I have rewritten your `is_prime` and `largest_prime_under` functions.

```
#!/bin/bash

is_prime() {
    local n="$1"
    
    if (( n==2 )) || (( n==3 )); then
        return 0       # 0 is 'true' in Unix sh convention..
    fi
    
    if (( n<1 )) || (( n % 2==0 )) || (( n % 3==0 )); then
        return 1       # 1 is 'false' in Unix sh convention..
    fi

    for (( i=5; i*i<=n; i+=6 )); do
        if (( n % i==0)) || (( n % (i+2)==0 )); then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}

largest_prime_under() {
    local x=$1
    if [[ ! "$x" =~ ^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)$ ]]; then
        echo 'Input must be a natural number (0,1,2,3,...)'
        return 1
    fi    
    
    if (( x<2 )); then
        echo 'Input must be greater than 2'
        return 1
    fi

    while (( x>=2 )); do 
        if is_prime "$x"; then
            echo "$x is largest prime less than or equal to $1"
            return 0
        fi
        (( x-- ))
    done
}
```

There is an explanation of the `is_prime` method [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285588/298607) and a deep dive on various methods for calculating primes [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625663/calculating-and-printing-the-nth-prime-number/9704912#9704912).

Know that this is not at all an optimal or general solution. With larger values of integers, the [gap between primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#) grows. With larger gaps, the function `largest_prime_under` may be calling `is_prime`  and recalculating the *same* composite numbers millions of times.

A more efficient solution would cache all primes up to and including a given number and return the last number. With Bash, however, large arrays are not efficient at random access (ie, `array[n]` is not necessarily `O(1)` and introduces another level of problems. You would need to use a higher level language and implement something like [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).)

As a practical matter, I was able to use these functions (on an M3 Mac) and receive accurate values from these functions as follows :

1. values up to 10^12 with results in milliseconds;
2. values up to 10^15 with results in seconds;
3. values up to 10^17 with results in minutes.

With larger values, it is unusably slow. It is likely worse than quadratic complexity but useable on modern hardware up to roughly 10^12.