# Prime Number generator with recursion and list comprehension

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension, primes, sieve

I am a newbie to Haskell programming and have trouble understanding how the below list comprehension expands.

```
primes = sieve [2..] 
sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x <-xs, x `mod` p /= 0]
```

Can someone correct me how the `sieve` expansion works:

- As we are pattern matching in `sieve`, `p` would associate to `2` and `x`s from `[3..]`.
- Next, in the list comprehension `x<-3`, but then how can we call sieve with just `3` when there is no short-circuit.

Other thing I do not understand is how recursion works here.

I think it would be clear if one could expand the above one step at a time for first few numbers, say until `5`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help explain this chunk of haskell code that outputs a stream of primes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764163/help-explain-this-chunk-of-haskell-code-that-outputs-a-stream-of-primes)

Comment: No it is not duplicate, please read my question again

Comment: It is if you inline everything in one function and translate the guard in list comprehension to `filter`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's do some equational reasoning.

```
primes = sieve [2..]
sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p /= 0]
```

The `[2..]` is sintactic sugar for `[2, 3, 4, 5, ...]` so

```
primes = sieve [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
```

Inline `sieve` once:

```
primes = 2 : sieve [x | x <- [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...], x `mod` 2 /= 0]
```

First, `x` gets value `3` which passes the `mod 2` filter

```
primes = 2 : sieve (3 : [x | x <- [4, 5, 6, 7, ...], x `mod` 2 /= 0])
```

Inline `sieve` again (I renamed `x` to `y` to prevent confusions)

```
primes = 2 : 3 : sieve [y | y <- [x | x <- [4, 5, 6, 7, ...], x `mod` 2 /= 0], 
                            y `mod` 3 /= 0]
```

Now `x = 4` fails the `mod 2` filter but `x = 5` passes it. So

```
primes = 2 : 3 : sieve [y | y <- 5 : [x | x <- [6, 7, 8, ...], x `mod` 2 /= 0], 
                            y `mod` 3 /= 0]
```

This `y = 5` also passes the `mod 3` filter so now we have

```
primes = 2 : 3 : sieve (5 : [y | y <- [x | x <- [6, 7, 8, ...], x `mod` 2 /= 0], 
                                 y `mod` 3 /= 0])
```

Expanding `sieve` one more time (`z` instead of `y`) gets us to

```
primes = 2 : 3 : 5 : sieve [z | z <- [y | y <- [x | x <- [6, 7, 8, ...], 
                                                    x `mod` 2 /= 0], 
                                          y `mod` 3 /= 0], 
                                z `mod` 5 /= 0]
```

And the expansion continues on the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an operational description of what `sieve` does.

To compute `sieve (x:xs)`:

1. Emit the leading element `x`.
2. From the tail `xs`, let `ys` be the list `xs` with all of the multiples of `x` removed.
3. To generate the next element, recursively call `sieve` on `ys` defined in step 2.

Here is how the first couple of terms are computed:

```
sieve [2..]
  = sieve (2:[3..])              -- x = 2, xs = [3..]
  = 2 : sieve ys
      where ys = [3..] with all of the multiples of 2 removed
               = [3,5,7,9,...]
  = 2 : sieve [3,5,7,9,...]
```

and then:

```
sieve [3,5,7,9,...]              -- x = 3, xs = [5,7,9,11,...]
  = 3 : sieve ys
      where ys = [5,7,9,11,13,15,17,...] with all of the multiples of 3 removed
               = [5,7,  11,13,   17,...]
  = 3 : sieve [5,7,11,13,17,...]
```

and then:

```
sieve [5,7,11,13,17,...]         -- x = 5, xs = [7,11,13,17..]
  = 5 : sieve ys
      where ys = [7, 11,13, 17,19,...]  with all of the multiples of 5 removed
               = [7, 11,13, 17,19,...]  (the first one will be 25, then 35,...)
  = 5 : sieve [7,11,13,17,19,...]
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using an auxiliary function

```
transform (p:xs) = [x | x <- xs, mod x p /= 0]
                 = filter (\x-> mod x p /= 0) xs  -- remove all multiples of p
                 = xs >>= noMult p                -- feed xs through a tester
-- where
noMult p x = [x | rem x p > 0]      -- keep x if not multiple of p
```

we can rewrite the `sieve` function as

```
       .=================================================+
       |                                                 |
       |  sieve input =                                  |
       |                  .===========================+  |
       |                  |                           |  |
 <~~~~~~~~~~ head input : | sieve (transform input )  |  |
       |                  |                           |  |
       |                  \___________________________|  |
       |                                                 |
       \_________________________________________________|
```

In an imperative pseudocode, we could write it as

```
sieve input =
    while (True) :
        yield (head input)           -- wait until it's yanked, and then
        input := transform input     -- advance and loop
```

This pattern of repeated applications is known as *iteration*:

```
iterate f x = loop x
  where
    loop x = x : loop (f x)   -- [x, a:=f x, b:=f a, c:=f b, ...]
```

So that

```
sieve xs = map head ( iterate transform xs )
```

Naturally, head element of each transformed sequence on each step will be a prime, since we've removed all the multiples of the preceding primes on previous steps.

Haskell is lazy, so transformations won't be done in full on each step, far from it -- only as much of the work will be done as needed. That means producing only the first element, and "making a notice" to perform the transformation further when asked:

```
<--  2 ---<    [2..]
<--  3 ---<    [3..] >>= noMult 2 
<--  5 ---<   ([4..] >>= noMult 2) >>= noMult 3 
<--  7 ---<  (([6..] >>= noMult 2) >>= noMult 3) >>= noMult 5
<-- 11 ---< ((([8..] >>= noMult 2) >>= noMult 3) >>= noMult 5) >>= noMult 7
            ...............
```

---

Incidentally, this should give us an idea: *3* needn't *really* be tested by *2*; *4..8* needn't *really* be tested by *3*, let alone *5* or *7*; *9..24* shouldn't *really* be tested by *5*; etc. What we want is the following:

```
<-- 2
<-- 3         --<  2(4),    [3..]
<-- 5,7       --<  3(9),    [4..]  >>= noMult 2 
<-- 11,...,23 --<  5(25),  ([9..]  >>= noMult 2) >>= noMult 3 
<-- 29,...,47 --<  7(49), (([25..] >>= noMult 2) >>= noMult 3) >>= noMult 5
                   ......................
```

i.e. we want the creation of each `>>= noMult p` filter [*postponed*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprimes%5D+postponed) until `p*p` is reached in the input.