# Prime sieve results in (me going to) stack overflow

Tags: performance, haskell, time-complexity, primes, sieve

For project euler i was looking for a way to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes because i expected it to be faster than my original implementation (and needed it to be so). I came up with this function:

```
sieve :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
sieve p (x:xs) | rem x p == 0 = sieve p xs
               | otherwise = x : (sieve x $ sieve p xs)
sieve _ [] = []
```

Which works, but hits the fan very fast, resulting in a stack overflow. I headed here for some advice and immediately struck a [spoiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764163/help-explain-this-chunk-of-haskell-code-that-outputs-a-stream-of-primes) which, to me, looks quite the same, but the difference in performance is outlandish. 
I still want to continue using my own implementation, and would like to know whether or not my function can be changed easily to use less memory.

Comment: [you should take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764163/help-explain-this-chunk-of-haskell-code-that-outputs-a-stream-of-primes#comment1648439_1764163)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has an exponential explosion inside it:

```
sieve p (x:xs) | rem x p == 0 = sieve p xs
               | otherwise = x : (sieve x $ sieve p xs)
--                                          ^^^^^^^       here!
--                                ^^^^^^^                 and here!
```

You intended for the inner `sieve` call to just continue filtering by `p`, but since you use the same `sieve` function, it will also start up new filters for new primes as it encounters them - but that's entirely superfluous since the "upper" level call will also start new filter for the same prime!

```
sieve 2 [3..]
 = 3 : sieve 3 (sieve 2 [4..])
 = 3 : sieve 3 (5 : sieve 5 (sieve 2 [6..]))
 = 3 : 5 : sieve 5 (sieve 3 (sieve 5 (sieve 2 [6..])))
....         -- ^^^               ^^^                      -- !!!
```

After *7* passes to the top through the four `sieve`s here, each will split in two creating four new `sieve 7`s, so there will be ***eight*** `sieve`s in the chain!! Even worse, when *9* - the composite! - goes through the sieves, it will split the *2*, the *7*s and the *5*, and will only be rejected by the *3*. So it's actually *worse* than exponential in number of primes *`n`*, and close to being exponential in the value of the last prime produced (which is *`~ n log(n)`*).

Change it to

```
sieve p (x:xs) | rem x p == 0 = sieve p xs
               | otherwise = x : (sieve x $ filter ((>0).(`rem` p)) xs)
```

and you get the code equivalent to the one you cite.

If you prefer to hand code everything, you could introduce a new argument, a Boolean flag controlling whether to start up new filters or not:

```
primes = 2 : sieve True 2 [3..]
sieve b p (x:xs) | rem x p == 0 = sieve b p xs
                 | b = x : (sieve b x $ sieve False p xs)
                 | otherwise = x : sieve b p xs
```