# Using a counter within a function Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, counter, higher-order-functions

I want to find a way to use a counter within a function where the counter is also a variable within the recursive function. An example of this is with a program that takes a list and then "sifts" through it until it finds all the numbers within it that are multiples of i:

```
(define (multiples-of lst) (lambda (i) (if (> i 3))
                               '()
                               (multiplefilter (ismultipleof (+ i 1)) (lst)))))
```

where `ismultipleof` checks if the car of each list is a multiple of `i + 1` (with i starting at 1) and then the `multiplefilter` is a separate function that scraps any values of the list that are not multiples of `i`.  So that if I put in the list `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)` the output would just be `(6 12)`. The biggest issue is getting said counter to work within the function.

Comment: I've tried using (cond as well in place of the if statement but I still get the same issue of it not working.

Comment: It looks like the way you are defining functions is a little messed up. Could you include an example of how you want to call this procedure?

Comment: Could you add a little clarification? The question references three functions: `multiplesof`, `multiplefilter`, and `multipleof` (no 's'). Is that a typo or what you want?

Comment: Also, as I understand the question, `multipleof` is a predicate that would return #t for multiples of 4 in your example, i.e `'(4 8 12)`. If that is true, it seems like your example should return just `'(12)`. Again, is that what you intend?

Comment: the names are a bit messy but that is the intention. The way I wanted to numbers to work would be a loop (so check if the list is multiples of 1, 2, and 3. I'll adjust the code to make it easier to read. I would be calling it either through a different function or by itself, right now I'm just having trouble with the loop aspect of it.

Comment: [mcve], please. otherwise it is impossible to understand. for a possibly related example of using the let-over-lambda technique, see `not-divisible-by` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340403/849891).

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a simple function that uses a counter in its execution. `range` just returns a list of integers from 0 up to (- n 1). It's just as easy to write something that increments a counter.

```lisp
(define (range n)
  (let loop ((acc '())
             (list-start (- n 1)))
    (if (negative? list-start)
        acc
        (loop (cons list-start acc) (- list-start 1)))))
```

This function counts down rather than up because recursion usually builds lists "backwards". Counting down just avoids the need call `reverse` on the `acc` when the recursion is finished.

Iteration is usually accomplished with recursion in Scheme instead of `for` loops as in some languages. In particular, recursion from the tail is something to strive for since it will not "blow the stack".