# Why might the Scheme `filter` form not process list elements 'in order'?

Tags: filter, scheme, sequencing, r6rs, r7rs

> `(filter procedure list)` applies *`procedure`* to each element of *`list`*
> and returns a new list containing only the elements for which *`procedure`*
> returns true.
> ([R. Kent Dybvig *The Scheme Programming Language*](https://scheme.com/tspl4/canned/about.html))
> ([online](https://scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:s55))

What may not be apparent from this description is that, while the elements in the returned
list occur in the same order as in `list`, the order of calls of `procedure` is not
specified in R6RS. (Racket, however, applies the procedure "to each element from first to last")

A recently active [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328941/modified-sieve-for-finding-prime-numbers-in-scheme/66340403#66340403)
mentions that it requires a `filterfunc` which works over its argument list
*in order*. How should one write this function?

An answer with my explanation of the issue is supplied.

Answer (score 2):

What order might a Scheme implementation use, and why? Let's try it (all code run in Chez Scheme REPL):

1. Display order of applications

```
> (filter (lambda (x) (display x) (even? x))
    '(0 1 2 3 4 5)))
452301(0 2 4)
>
```

2. Why this order?
   R6RS implementations **must** check that *`list`* is a ***proper list***

- ends with the empty list:

```
> (filter (lambda (x) (display x) (even? x))
    '(0 1 2 . 3)))
Exception in filter: (0 1 2 . 3) is not a proper list
>
```

- no circularity:

```
> (define xs '(0 1 2 3))
> (set-cdr! (cdddr xs) (cdr xs))
> (filter (lambda (x) (display x) (even? x)) xs)
Exception in filter: (0 1 2 3 1 2 ...) is not a proper list
>
```

- the implementation of `filter` in Chez Scheme which checks these requirements
  while filtering, resulting in the "452301" order of predicate applications,
  can be seen [here](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/main/s/5_2.ss)
  (lines 589-617: a version is included as a spoiler below as an alternative to scrolling through
  the source on github)

3. [What?](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/main/s/5_2.ss)
   The Chez Scheme code uses a ["tortoise and hare" algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd%27s_tortoise_and_hare)
   to detect cycles. Without error checks the code could be:

```
> (let ([filter
    (lambda (pred? ls)
      (let f ([fast ls])
        (if (pair? fast)
          (let ([rest (f (cdr fast))])
            (if (pred? (car fast))
              (cons (car fast) rest)
              rest))
          '())))])
  
    (filter (lambda (x) (display x) (even? x))
      '(0 1 2 3 4 5)))
543210(0 2 4)
>
```

(the identifier `fast` is used to match the Chez Scheme code: could be `ls` otherwise)

4. How can one change this to call `pred?` "from first to last"?

- replace the `rest` variable with an accumulator (compare the following with 3 above;
  the changes are small, but filtered elements are `cons`ed to acc,
  so it has to be reversed to give the result):

```
> (let ([filter
    (lambda (pred? ls)
      (let f ([fast ls] [acc '()])
        (if (pair? fast)
          (f (cdr fast)
             (if (pred? (car fast))
               (cons (car fast) acc)
               acc))
          (reverse acc))))])
  
    (filter (lambda (x) (display x) (even? x))
      '(0 1 2 3 4 5)))
012345(0 2 4)
>
```

So 4 could be used as the required `filterfunc`. It would be an interesting exercise
to add error checks like the Chez Scheme implementation, which is effectively:

> `(define (filter pred? ls)`
>        `(unless (procedure? pred?)`
>          `(error #f "not a procedure" pred?))`
>        `(or (let f ((pred? pred?) (fast ls) (slow ls))`
>              `(if (pair? fast)`
>                  `(let ((fast1 (cdr fast)))`
>                    `(if (pair? fast1)`
>                        `(and (not (eq? fast1 slow))`
>                             `(let ((fast2 (cdr fast1)))`
>                               `(let ((rest (f pred? fast2 (cdr slow))))`
>                                 `(and rest`
>                                      `(if (pred? (car fast))`
>                                          `(if (pred? (car fast1))`
>                                              `(if (eq? rest fast2)`
>                                                  `fast`
>                                                  `(list* (car fast)`
>                                                         `(car fast1) rest))`
>                                              `(cons (car fast) rest))`
>                                          `(if (pred? (car fast1))`
>                                              `(if (eq? rest fast2)`
>                                                  `fast1`
>                                                  `(cons (car fast1) rest))`
>                                              `rest))))))`
>                        `(and (null? fast1)`
>                             `(if (pred? (car fast))`
>                                 `fast`
>                                 `'()))))`
>                  `(and (null? fast) '())))`
>            `(error #f "circular/improper list" ls)))`

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

It involves you should not use mutation of some external variable inside procedure and it supposes the implementation may apply parallelism, for example map-reduce.