# Can this prime sieve code be further simplified in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, primes, sieve, non-exhaustive-patterns

The code works well

```
primes = next [2 ..]
  where
    next (p : ps) = p : next ts
      where
        ts = filter (\x -> mod x p /= 0) ps
```

Just GHCI think there is a incomplete patter in `next`.

Well, this is correct from a grammatical point of view.

But obviously the input of 'next' cannot be empty.

So is there a solution other than adding the declaration
(`{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-incomplete-patterns #-}`)?

Comment: I make a mistake. the output miss the first `2`. I've been fixed it by changing `head ts` to `p`

Comment: You can of course just add a case `next [] = undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exhaustiveness checker knows that `next` has type `Num a => [a] -> [a]`. The empty list is a valid argument to `next`, even if you never actually *call* `next` on the empty list.

The key here is that you don't really *want* `Num a => [a]` as your argument type. You know it will only be called on an infinite list, so use a type that doesn't *have* finite lists as values.

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

sequence :: Num a => a -> Stream a
sequence x = Cons x (sequence (x + 1))

filterStream :: (a -> Bool) -> Stream a -> Stream a
filterStream p (Cons x xs) | p x = Cons x (filterStream p xs)
                           | otherwise = filterStream p xs

-- Since you'll probably want a list of values, not just a stream of them, at some point.
toList :: Stream a -> [a]
toList (Cons x xs) = x : toList xs

primes :: Stream Integer
primes = next (sequence 2)
  where 
    next (Cons x xs) = Cons x xs'
      where xs' = filterStream (\x -> mod x p /= 0) xs
```

The [`Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream) library provides a module [`Data.Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-Stream.html) that defines the [`Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-Stream.html#t:Stream) type and numerous analogs to list functions.

```
import qualified Data.Stream as S

-- S.toList exists as well.

primes :: Stream Integer
primes = next (S.fromList [2..])
  where next (Cons x xs) = Cons x (S.filter (\x -> mod x p /= 0) xs)
```

Comment: Calling `S.fromList` is just hiding the incomplete pattern match in a library call. `S.iterate (1+) 2` seems like the right away to guarantee totality.

Comment: a link to`Data.Stream` please.

Comment: Hm, indeed I can't find it either. It's a well-known educational device, but maybe so simple that nobody uses the simple version in practice?

Comment: @amalloy I've found it now! on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?=&hoogle=Data.Stream%20is%3Amodule&scope=), I clicked the "is:module" toggle this time and it showed up in the middle of the results list.

Comment: (couldn't find it before, when I first commented)

Answer (score 0):

You've already got a proper answer to your question. For completeness, the other option is just to add the unneeded clause that *we know* will never be called:

```
primes = next [2 ..]
  where
  next (p : xs) =
       p : next [x | x <- xs, mod x p > 0]
  next _ = undefined
```

Another, more "old-style" solution, is to analyze the argument by explicit calls  to `head` and `tail` (very much *not* recommended, in general):

```
primes = next [2 ..]
  where
  next xs = let { p = head xs } in
       p : next [x | x <- tail xs, mod x p > 0]
```

This could perhaps count as a simplification.

On an unrelated note, you write that it "works well". Unfortunately, while indeed producing the correct results, it does so very slowly. Because of always taking only *one* element at a time off the input list, its time complexity is *quadratic* in the number *n* of primes produced. In other words, `primes !! n` takes time quadratic in *`n`*. [Empirically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth),

```
> primes !! 1000
7927     -- (0.27 secs, 102987392 bytes)
> primes !! 2000
17393    -- (1.00 secs, 413106616 bytes)
> primes !! 3000
27457    -- (2.23 secs, 952005872 bytes)

> logBase (2/1) (1.00 / 0.27)
1.8889686876112561                -- n^1.9
> logBase (3/2) (2.23 / 1.00)
1.9779792870810489                -- n^2.0
```

In fact the whole bunch of the elements may be taken from the input at once, up to the *square* of the current prime, with the code thus taking only about *~ n<sup>1.5</sup>* time, give or take a *log* factor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

primes_ = 2 : next primes_ [3 ..] 
  where 
  next (p : ps) (span (< p*p) -> (h, xs)) = 
      h ++ next ps [x | x <- xs, mod x p > 0]
  next _ _ = undefined
```

Empirically, again, we get

```
> primes !! 3000
27457     -- (0.08 secs,   29980864 bytes)
> primes !! 30000
350381    -- (1.81 secs,  668764336 bytes)
> primes !! 60000
746777    -- (4.74 secs, 1785785848 bytes)
> primes !! 100000
1299721   -- (9.87 secs, 3633306112 bytes)

> logBase (6/3)  (4.74 / 1.81)
1.388897361815054                 -- n^1.4
> logBase (10/6) (9.87 / 4.74)
1.4358377567888103                -- n^1.45
```

As we can see here, the complexity advantage expresses itself as an enormous speedup in absolute terms as well.

So then *this* sieve is equivalent to the *optimal* trial division, unlike the one in the question. Of course when it was first proposed [in 1976](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871918/849891), Haskell had no view patterns yet, and in fact there was yet no Haskell itself.