# Recursive function causing a stack overflow

Tags: recursion, clojure, primes, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I am trying to write a simple sieve function to calculate prime numbers in clojure.  I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960980/fast-prime-number-generation-in-clojure) question about writing an efficient sieve function, but I am not to that point yet.  Right now I am just trying to write a very simple (and slow) sieve.  Here is what I have come up with:

```
(defn sieve [potentials primes]
  (if-let [p (first potentials)]
    (recur (filter #(not= (mod % p) 0) potentials) (conj primes p))
    primes))
```

For small ranges it works fine, but causes a stack overflow for large ranges:

```
user=> (sieve (range 2 30) [])
[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29]
user=> (sieve (range 2 15000) [])
java.lang.StackOverflowError (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

I thought that by using `recur` this would be a non-stack-consuming looping construct?  What am I missing?

Comment: +1 for having stack overflow in the title of your question

Comment: Funny; works for me. What version of Clojure are you using, with what JVM, on what platform? Can you run `(range 2 15000)` without overflow?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10, Java 1.6.0_15, latest snapshot of Clojure 1.2.0

Comment: Yes, I get an overflow at 15000.  Can you run one million without overflowing?

Comment: The title should be "**non recursive** function causing stack overflow".

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're being hit by `filter`'s laziness. Change `(filter ...)` to `(doall (filter ...))` in your `recur` form and the problem should go away.

A more in-depth explanation:

The call to `filter` returns a lazy seq, which materialises actual elements of the filtered seq as required. As written, your code stacks `filter` upon `filter` upon `filter`..., adding one more level of `filter`ing at each iteration; at some point this blows up. The solution is to force the whole result at each iteration so that the next one will do its filtering on a fully realised seq and return a fully realised seq instead of adding an extra layer of lazy seq processing; that's what `doall` does.

Comment: any thoughts how to find this out? maybe something like macroexpand?

Comment: Have a look at the stack trace, I'd say. A pile of `clojure.lang.LazySeq` method calls would be a good indication that the problem is laziness-related.

Answer (score -1):

Algorithmically the problem is that you continue filtering when there's no more purpose to it. Stopping as early as possible achieves quadratic reduction in recursion depth (`sqrt(n)` vs. `n`):

```
(defn sieve [potentials primes]    
  (if-let [p (first potentials)]
      (if (> (* p p) (last potentials))
        (concat primes potentials)
        (recur (filter (fn [n] (not= (mod n p) 0)) potentials)
               (conj primes p)))
    primes))
```

Runs OK for 16,000 (performing just 30 iterations instead of 1862), and for 160,000 too, [on ideone](http://ideone.com/lfhNhk). Even runs 5% faster without the `doall`.