# Clojure - tail recursive sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: algorithm, clojure, functional-programming, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have this implementation of the sieve of Eratosthenes in Clojure:

```
(defn sieve [n]
  (loop [last-tried 2 sift (range 2 (inc n))]
    (if
      (or (nil? last-tried) (> last-tried n))
      sift
      (let [filtered (filter #(or (= % last-tried) (< 0 (rem % last-tried))) sift)]
        (let [next-to-try (first (filter #(> % last-tried) filtered))]
        (recur next-to-try filtered))))))
```

For larger `n` (like 20000) it ends with stack overflow. Why doesn't tail call elimination work here? How to fix it?

Comment: As a side note, but this is not the sieve of Eratosthenes. SoE performs no remainder operations, just addition and "crossing out". See http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf for an extended discussion (it's a great read!); for a beautiful "incremental" SoE implementation in Clojure by Christophe Grand, see http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/07/30/everybody-loves-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes/ (it's also the fastest version I've seen so far).

Comment: @Michał Marczyk thanks. I would say that "crossing out" is equivalent of "filtering", and "addition" in this algorithm is equivalent of "multiplication" and consequently "remainder".

Comment: Not really. The result is, of course, the same, but the algorithmic complexity is wildly different.

Comment: the article is very good with math but unfortunately does poor job with words explaining the math. the difference is between iterative removal of composites tested by contiguous increasing chunks of primes *(first 1, first 2, first 3 primes, first 4 primes, ...)* , vs. independent production of composites each from *its prime factors only* ( `p --> {p*p, p*p+p, p*p+2*p, ...}` ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem: `filter` does lazy evaluation, so each new level of filtering hangs around on the call stack.

Fix: Change `(filter ...)` to `(doall (filter ...))`.

See the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the backtrace

```
(try
 (sieve 200000)
 (catch java.lang.StackOverflowError e
  (.printStackTrace e)))
```

it looks like this:

```
...
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:440)
at clojure.core$seq__4176.invoke(core.clj:103)
at clojure.core$filter__5033$fn__5035.invoke(core.clj:1751)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:56)
...
```

It's too many filters that's causing the overflow, not the loop.

Unfortunately, I don't see an obvious solution for this.

Comment: The clue was in the LazySeq. Clojures implementation of Laziness has a few gotchas this being one of them.

Comment: you've correctly identified the main algorithmic problem (as opposed to just technical). an obvious solution is to stop filtering as soon as there's no more need to filter. and that is, when `(> (* last-tried last-tried) n)`. For 20000, that means trading recursion depth of  roughly 2000, for just about 30.

Comment: (indeed [for 16,000](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41621006/849891) it's 30 vs 1862 nested filters).

Answer (score 0):

I second Michal Marczyk's comment about checking out cgrande's beautiful incremental SoE. I did some really primitive benchmarks and put them up at http://clojure.roboloco.net/?p=100, for those curious about lazy prime generator performance.