# OutOfMemoryError in lazy-seq

Tags: clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursive function causing a stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow)

Working through the example lazy-seq [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/lazy-seq#example_1000).

```
(defn sieve [s]
  (cons (first s)
        (lazy-seq (sieve (filter #(not= 0 (mod % (first s)))
                             (rest s))))))
```

If I try to generate more than a couple of thousand primes or so, I get an OutOfMemoryError.  Based on my research (but I am very new to clojure) I suspect this may be a problem of the class "hold onto head" but cannot figure out why that would be or how it might be remedied.  How can this function be altered so as not to run out of memory when generating larger numbers of primes?

Comment: Also asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980587/clojure-tail-recursive-sieve-of-eratosthenes, answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this, this answers my question, I thought I had searched sufficiently, apparently not.

Comment: Although, after working through it, it doesn't actually seem to solve my issue.

Comment: There is this link http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2009/07/30/everybody-loves-the-sieve-of-eratosthenes/ which has a efficient lazy prime definition.

Comment: That cgrand code is beautiful, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use version without creating lazy sequence. It works faster and cheaper:

```
 (defn sieve* [res s]
      (if (empty? s)
        res
        (recur (conj res (first s))
               (filter #(not= 0 (mod % (first s)))
                       (rest s)))))

(defn sieve [n]
  (sieve* [] (range 2 n)))

(sieve 10000)
=> [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 ... 9941 9949 9967 9973]
```

And here is more efficient version:

```
(defn sieve* [res n maxn]
  (if (> n maxn)
    res
    (if (some #(= 0 (mod n %))
              (take (round (sqrt (count res))) res))
      (recur res (inc n) maxn)
      (recur (conj res n) (inc n) maxn))))

(defn sieve [n]
  (sieve* [] 2 n))

(last (sieve 1000000))
=> 999983
```

**Update.** Pretty fast/cheap lazy version

```
(defn primes-seq* [primes]
  (let [last-prime (last primes)]
    (cons last-prime
          (lazy-seq
           (primes-seq*
            (conj primes
                  (first (let [compare-primes
                               (take (round (sqrt (count primes)))
                                     primes)]
                           (drop-while (fn [n]
                                         (some #(= 0 (mod n %))
                                               compare-primes))
                                       (iterate inc (inc last-prime)))))))))))


(def primes-seq (primes-seq* [2]))

(last (take 50000 primes-seq))
=> 611953
```

Comment: I would prefer a lazy solution, thanks.

Comment: @richguy No problem. I've added lazy version.

Answer (score 1):

The given algorithm works by "remembering" all the previous primes, so you are going to blow the stack if you keep going long enough.

The following may be less efficient but will not use up memory (adapted from my [4clojure](http://4clojure.com) solution to [#116](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/116)):

```
(defn prime-seq []
  (letfn [(is-prime [x]
            (not (some #(= (rem x %) 0) (range 2 x))))]
    (filter is-prime (range))))

(take 20 (prime-seq))
;=> (0 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61)
(nth (prime-seq) 10000)
;=> 104723
```

Comment: This works but as you say is pretty slow.