# Clojure: What is the underlying data structure of a lazy sequence?

Tags: data-structures, clojure, lazy-sequences

As stated above, what is the underlying data structure of a lazy sequence ?
Is it a list ? If it is, then what kind of list is it ? Where can I find references about this ?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247045/how-are-lazy-sequences-implemented-in-clojure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data structure is a `clojure.lang.Lazyseq`, defined [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LazySeq.java). The [`lazy-seq`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L642) macro creates such.

As you can see, a `LazySeq` is essentially a linked list which starts life with a thunk (zero-parameter function) member `fn`. When the sequence is realized, `fn` is used to generate data member `s` or `sv` and is itself annulled. I can't quite figure out how `s` and `sv` relate to one another.