# How to forget head(GC'd) for lazy-sequences in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, garbage-collection, lazy-sequences

Let's say I have a **huge** `lazy seq` and I want to iterate it so I can process on the data that I get during the iteration.

The thing is I want to **lose head(GC'd)** of `lazy seq`(that processed) so I can work on seqs that have *millions of data* without having `OutofMemoryException`.

I have *3 examples* that I'm not sure.

Could you provide **best practices(examples)** for that purpose?

Do these functions lose head?

Example 1

```
(defn lose-head-fn
  [lazy-seq-coll]
  (when (seq (take 1 lazy-seq-coll))
    (do
      ;;do some processing...(take 10000 lazy-seq-coll)
      (recur (drop 10000 lazy-seq-coll)))))
```

Example 2

```
(defn lose-head-fn
  [lazy-seq-coll]
  (loop [i lazy-seq-coll]
    (when (seq (take 1 i))
      (do
        ;;do some processing...(take 10000 i)
        (recur (drop 10000 i))))))
```

Example 3

```
(doseq [i lazy-seq-coll]
  ;;do some processing...
  )
```

**Update:** Also there is an explanation in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247417/2204772)

Comment: As far as i know, all of the above would lose head (first two are obvious, since you manually drop the head, while `doseq`'s doc claims that it doesn't retain head). So if the `lazy-seq-coll` you pass to the function isn't bound somewhere else with `def` or `let` and used later, there should be nothing to worry about. So `(lose-head-fn (range))` won't eat all your memory, while `(def r (range)) (lose-head-fn r)` probably would

Comment: and the only best practive i could think of, is not to `def` possibly infinite (or just huge) sequences, because all of their realized items would live forever in the var

Comment: @leetwinski This is exactly right. I hope you will post it as an answer so there will be something contradicting the other answer, which is currently wrong.

Comment: @leetwinski yes you should post it as an answer with additional information so new comers can understand!

Comment: thanks! I wasn't 100% sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**copy of my above comments**

As far as I know, all of the above would lose head (first two are obvious, since you manually drop the head, while `doseq`'s doc claims that it doesn't retain head).

That means that if the `lazy-seq-coll` you pass to the function isn't bound somewhere else with `def` or `let` and used later, there should be nothing to worry about. So `(lose-head-fn (range))` won't eat all your memory, while

```
(def r (range)) 

(lose-head-fn r)
```

probably would.

And the only best practice I could think of is not to `def` possibly infinite (or just huge) sequences, because all of their realized items would live forever in the var.

Comment: See the discussion called [*Don't hang (onto) your head*](https://clojure.org/reference/lazy#_don_t_hang_onto_your_head) in the article [*Making Clojure Lazier*](https://clojure.org/reference/lazy). I think it confirms your conclusions.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you must **be careful not to retain a reference either locally or globally for a part of a lazy seq that precedes another which involves excessive computation**.

For example:

```
(let [nums (range)
      first-ten (take 10 nums)]
  (+ (last first-ten) (nth nums 100000000)))
=> 100000009
```

This takes about 2 seconds on a modern machine.  How about this though? The difference is the last line, where the order of arguments to `+` is swapped:

```
;; Don't do this!
(let [nums (range)
      first-ten (take 10 nums)]
  (+ (nth nums 100000000) (last first-ten)))
```

You'll hear your chassis/cpu fans come to life, and if you're running `htop` or similar, you'll see memory usage grow rather quickly (about 1G in the first several seconds for me).

#### What's going on?

Much like a linked list, elements in a lazy seq in clojure reference the portion of the seq that comes next. In the second example above, `first-ten` is needed for the second argument to `+`. Thus, even though `nth` is happy to hold no references to anything (after all, it's just finding an index in a long list), `first-ten` refers to a portion of the sequence that, as stated above, must hold onto references to the rest of the sequence.

The first example, by contrast, computes `(last first-ten)`, and after this, `first-ten` is no longer used. Now the only reference to any portion of the lazy sequence is `nums`. As `nth` does its work, each portion of the list that it's finished with is no longer needed, **and since nothing else refers to the list in this block**, as `nth` walks the list, the memory taken by the sequence that has been examined can be garbage collected.

Consider this:

```
;; Don't do this!
(let [nums (range)]
  (time (nth nums 1e8))
  (time (nth nums 1e8)))
```

Why does this have a similar result as the second example above? Because the sequence will be cached (held in memory) on the first realization of it (the first `(time (nth nums 1e8))`), **because nums is being used on the next line**.  If, instead, we use a *different* sequence for the second `nth`, then there is no need to cache the first one, so it can be discarded as it's processed:

```
(let [nums (range)]
  (time (nth nums 1e8))
  (time (nth (range) 1e8)))
"Elapsed time: 2127.814253 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 2042.608043 msecs"
```

So as you work with large lazy seqs, consider whether anything is still pointing to the list, and if anything is (global vars being a common one), then it **will** be held in memory.