# How do I filter elements from a sequence based on indexes

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence `s` and a list of indexes into this sequence `indexes`. How do I retain only the items given via the indexes?

Simple example:

```
(filter-by-index '(a b c d e f g) '(0 2 3 4)) ; => (a c d e)
```

My usecase:

```
(filter-by-index '(c c# d d# e f f# g g# a a# b) '(0 2 4 5 7 9 11)) ; => (c d e f g a b)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make a list of vectors containing the items combined with the indexes,

```
(def with-indexes (map #(vector %1 %2 ) ['a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f] (range)))
#'clojure.core/with-indexes
 with-indexes
([a 0] [b 1] [c 2] [d 3] [e 4] [f 5])
```

filter this list

```
lojure.core=> (def filtered (filter #(#{1 3 5 7} (second % )) with-indexes))
#'clojure.core/filtered
clojure.core=> filtered
([b 1] [d 3] [f 5])
```

then remove the indexes.

```
clojure.core=> (map first filtered)                                          
(b d f)
```

then we thread it together with the "thread last" macro

```
(defn filter-by-index [coll idxs] 
    (->> coll
        (map #(vector %1 %2)(range)) 
        (filter #(idxs (first %)))
        (map second)))
clojure.core=> (filter-by-index ['a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g] #{2 3 1 6}) 
(b c d g)
```

The moral of the story is, break it into small independent parts, test them, then compose them into a working function.

Comment: Great, thx! I had something like that, but I couldn't figure out to use "range" properly.

Comment: ohh and note that I switched the list of indexes for a vector of indexes. This is because sets can be used as a filter function.

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`keep-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep-indexed):

```
(defn filter-by-index [coll idxs]
  (keep-indexed #(when ((set idxs) %1) %2) 
                coll))
```

Another version using explicit recur and lazy-seq:

```
(defn filter-by-index [coll idxs]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [idx (first idxs)]
     (if (zero? idx)
       (cons (first coll)
             (filter-by-index (rest coll) (rest (map dec idxs))))
       (filter-by-index (drop idx coll)
                        (map #(- % idx) idxs))))))
```

Comment: This is the best answer and it's almost at the bottom!

Answer (score 10):

The easiest solution is to use `map`:

```
(defn filter-by-index [coll idx]
  (map (partial nth coll) idx))
```

Answer (score 7):

I like Jonas's answer, but neither version will work well for an infinite sequence of indices: the first tries to create an infinite set, and the latter runs into a stack overflow by [layering too many unrealized lazy sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2946764/625403) on top of each other. To avoid both problems you have to do slightly more manual work:

```
(defn filter-by-index [coll idxs]
  ((fn helper [coll idxs offset]
     (lazy-seq
      (when-let [idx (first idxs)]
        (if (= idx offset)
          (cons (first coll)
                (helper (rest coll) (rest idxs) (inc offset)))
          (helper (rest coll) idxs (inc offset))))))
   coll idxs 0))
```

With this version, both `coll` and `idxs` can be infinite and you will still have no problems:

```
user> (nth (filter-by-index (range) (iterate #(+ 2 %) 0)) 1e6)
2000000
```

Edit: not trying to single out Jonas's answer: *none* of the other solutions work for infinite index sequences, which is why I felt a solution that does is needed.

Comment: I wonder which is a more remote edge-case, an infinite sequence of indices to keep, or indices not in monotonically increasing order.

Comment: @AlexTaggart good point, since it's impossible to cater for both I guess you have to make a decision. Laziness seems more important to me, as part of the general Clojure philosophy, but for a given instance of the problem it could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case and came up with another easy solution. This one expects vectors.

I've changed the function name to match other similar clojure functions.

```
(defn select-indices [coll indices]
   (reverse (vals (select-keys coll indices))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn filter-by-index [seq idxs]
  (let [idxs (into #{} idxs)]
    (reduce (fn [h [char idx]]
              (if (contains? idxs idx)
                (conj h char) h))
            [] (partition 2 (interleave seq (iterate inc 0))))))

(filter-by-index [\a \b \c \d \e \f \g] [0 2 3 4])
=>[\a \c \d \e]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=> (defn filter-by-index [src indexes]
     (reduce (fn [a i] (conj a (nth src i))) [] indexes))

=> (filter-by-index '(a b c d e f g) '(0 2 3 4))
[a c d e]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not what was asked, but after reading these answers, I realized in my own personal use case, what I actually wanted was basically filtering by a mask.

So here was my take. Hopefully this will help someone else.

```
(defn filter-by-mask [coll mask]
  (filter some? (map #(if %1 %2) mask coll)))

(defn make-errors-mask [coll]
  (map #(nil? (:error %)) coll))
```

Usage

```
(let [v [{} {:error 3} {:ok 2} {:error 4 :yea 7}]
    data ["one" "two" "three" "four"]
    mask (make-errors-mask v)]
    (filter-by-mask data mask))

; ==> ("one" "three")
```