# Map only selected elements in a list

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a list of elements `L`, a function `g`, and a list of indices `I`.

Then, how can I map the function `g` only to the elements of the list `L` specified by the indices `I`?

For instance, if `g` is the squaring function, `L` is the list `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` and `I` is the set of indices `(1 3 4)`, then I should obtain
`(1 4 3 16 25 6 7)`, that is the list `L` in which I squared the elements in positions `I`.

(The first index is 0, like it is used in the `nth` function)

I can do it in some way or another, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it.

Comment: This is, not quite a duplicate of, but very similar to [How do I filter elements from a sequence based on indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7744656/625403). The approaches there will provide some additional insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, without a library, you can just make use of [`map-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed):

```
(def I #{1 3 4})
(def L '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))

(defn g [n] (* n n))


(map-indexed #(if (I %) (g %2) %2) L))

; or, with explicit parameters

(map-indexed (fn [i n] (if (I i) (g n) n)) L)

; Both produce a lazy-list of (1 4 3 16 25 6 7)
```

Of course, with better names, this would be a lot more readable.

I have `I` as a set here instead of a list so lookups can be done efficiently. If you have it as a list originally, you can convert it to a set using `set`.

Also note, this produces a lazy-list. If you want a different structure, you can use `vec` for example to force it into a vector afterward.

Comment: contains? on a list is no good. It's not just show, it doesn't work.

Comment: @amalloy Whoops. Honestly it's been a good while since I've written Clojure. Apparently I'm starting to lose some fundamental knowledge. That's sad.

Answer (score 1):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :as s])
(use '[plumbing.core])
(s/transform [s/INDEXED-VALS (fn->> first (contains? #{1 3 4})) s/LAST]
             (fn [x] (* x x)) 
             '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you can do it with a simple `map` call:

```
(defn g [x]
  (* x x))

(def L '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
(def I '(1 3 4))
(map #(g (nth L %)) I)
;; => (4 16 25)
```

The mindset here is, for each indexes of `I`, I lookup the associated value in `L` and I compute `g` function over it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to loop over the desired indexes to change, using `assoc` to replace items in a vector:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test) )

(defn update-idx
  [data txfn idxs]
  (reduce
    (fn [result idx]
      (let [val-orig (get result idx)
            val-new  (txfn val-orig)]
        (assoc result idx val-new)))
    (vec data) ; coerce data to vector
    idxs))

(dotest
  (let [plus100 (fn [x] (+ 100 x))]
    (is= (update-idx (range 10) plus100 [2 3 5 7]))
    [0 1 102 103 4 105 6 107 8 9]))
```