# Overflow while using recur in clojure

Tags: clojure, primes, tail-recursion

I have a simple prime number calculator in clojure (an inefficient algorithm, but I'm just trying to understand the behavior of recur for now).  The code is:

```
(defn divisible [x,y] (= 0 (mod x y)))

(defn naive-primes [primes candidates] 
  (if (seq candidates)
      (recur  (conj primes (first candidates)) 
              (remove (fn [x] (divisible x (first candidates))) candidates))
      primes)
)
```

This works as long as I am not trying to find too many numbers.  For example

```
(print (sort (naive-primes [] (range 2 2000))))
```

works.  For anything requiring more recursion, I get an overflow error.

```
    (print (sort (naive-primes [] (range 2 20000))))
```

will not work.  In general, whether I use recur or call naive-primes again without the attempt at TCO doesn't appear to make any difference.  Why am I getting errors for large recursions while using recur?

Comment: Does recur require loop to get tail recursion? I don't see loop in your code. I'd make this an answer, but I'm still learning Clojure.

Comment: Your code works for me in Clojure 1.2.1 and 1.3. The only error I eventually get is an `OutOfMemoryError` when finding primes up to 200,000.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, no, recur can be used in this fashion (just within a function body) as well. See http://clojure.org/special_forms#recur.

Comment: @HansEngel running at the repl in 1.3, I get a stack overflow error when finding primes up to 200,000.  Explanation below.

Comment: My apologies for not finding this before posting.  My question was similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow

Comment: Why don't you use the anonymous function literal and write something like: `(remove (#(divisible % (first candidates))) candidates)`?

Comment: @Yehonathan, Is that going to help with the memory issue, or is it just a stylistic suggestion?

Comment: stylistic only. But style is essential in clojure.

Comment: why `sort` though? aren't the primes created already in order? --- I've added an algorithm-improving answer at the earlier question btw, that doesn't need the `doall` (will vote to close this one as a duplicate, as this is what it is :) ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive function causing a stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`recur` always uses tail recursion, regardless of whether you are recurring to a loop or a function head.  The issue is the calls to `remove`.  `remove` calls `first` to get the element from the underlying seq and checks to see if that element is valid.  If the underlying seq was created by a call to `remove`, you get another call to `first`.  If you call `remove` 20000 times on the same seq, calling `first` requires calling `first` 20000 times, and none of the calls can be tail recursive.  Hence, the stack overflow error.

Changing `(remove ...)` to `(doall (remove ...))` fixes the problem, since it prevents the infinite stacking of `remove` calls (each one gets fully applied immediately and returns a concrete seq, not a lazy seq).  I think this method only ever keeps one candidates list in memory at one time, though I am not positive about this.  If so, it isn't too space inefficient, and a bit of testing shows that it isn't actually much slower.

Comment: Thanks.  It would have taken me forever to figure that out without your help.  Even though doall seems a little magical to me, this was extremely helpful!