# clojure - (Another one) StackOverflow with loop/recur

Tags: recursion, clojure

I know this is a *recurring* question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202500/overflow-while-using-recur-in-clojure), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896879/another-stack-overflow-on-loop-recur-in-clojure), and more), and I know that the problem is related to creating lazy sequencies, but I can't see why it fails.

The problem: I had written a (not very nice) quicksort algorithm to sort strings that uses loop/recur. But applied to 10000 elements, I get a StackOverflowError:

```
(defn qsort [list]
  (loop [[current & todo :as all] [list] sorted []]
    (cond 
       (nil? current) sorted 
       (or (nil? (seq current)) (= (count current) 1)) (recur todo (concat sorted current))
       :else (let [[pivot & rest] current
                  pred #(> (compare pivot %) 0)
                  lt (filter pred rest)
                  gte (remove pred rest)
                  work (list* lt [pivot] gte todo)] 
                (recur work sorted)))))
```

I used in this way:

```
(defn tlfnum [] (str/join (repeatedly 10 #(rand-int 10))))
(defn tlfbook [n] (repeatedly n #(tlfnum)))
(time (count (qsort (tlfbook 10000))))
```

And this is part of the stack trace:

```
  [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 49]
  [clojure.lang.RT seq "RT.java" 521]
  [clojure.core$seq__4357 invokeStatic "core.clj" 137]
  [clojure.core$concat$fn__4446 invoke "core.clj" 706]
  [clojure.lang.LazySeq sval "LazySeq.java" 40]
  [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 49]
  [clojure.lang.RT seq "RT.java" 521]
  [clojure.core$seq__4357 invokeStatic "core.clj" 137]]}
```

As far as I know, loop/recur performs tail call optimization, so no stack is used (is, in fact, an iterative process written using recursive syntax).

Reading other answers, and because of the stack trace, I see there's a problem with `concat` and adding a `doall` before `concat` solves the stack overflow problem. But... why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's part of the code for the two-arity version of concat.

```
(defn concat [x y]
  (lazy-seq
   (let [s (seq x)]
     ,,,))
  )
```

Notice that it uses two other functions, `lazy-seq`, and `seq`. `lazy-seq` is a bit like a lambda, it wraps some code without executing it yet. The code inside the `lazy-seq` block has to result in some kind of sequence value. When you call any sequence operation on the `lazy-seq`, then it will first evaluate the code ("realize" the lazy seq), and then perform the operation on the result.

```
(def lz (lazy-seq
         (println "Realizing!")
         '(1 2 3)))

(first lz)
;; prints "realizing"
;; => 1
```

Now try this:

```
(defn lazy-conj [xs x]
  (lazy-seq
   (println "Realizing" x)
   (conj (seq xs) x)))
```

Notice that it's similar to `concat`, it calls `seq` on its first argument, and returns a `lazy-seq`

```
(def up-to-hundred
  (reduce lazy-conj () (range 100)))

(first up-to-hundred)
;; prints "Realizing 99"
;; prints "Realizing 98"
;; prints "Realizing 97"
;; ...
;; => 99
```

Even though you asked for only the first element, it still ended up realizing the whole sequence. That's because realizing the outer "layer" results in calling `seq` on the next "layer", which realizes another lazy-seq, which again calls seq, etc. So it's a chain reaction that realizes everything, and each step consumes a stack frame.

```
(def up-to-ten-thousand
  (reduce lazy-conj () (range 10000)))

(first up-to-ten-thousand)
;;=> java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

You get the same problem when stacking `concat` calls. That's why for instance `(reduce concat ,,,)` is always a smell, instead you can use `(apply concat ,,,)` or `(into () cat ,,,)`.

Other lazy operators like `filter` and `map` can exhibit the exact same problem. If you really have a lot of transformation steps over a sequence consider using transducers instead.

```
;; without transducers: many intermediate lazy seqs and deep call stacks
(->> my-seq
     (map foo)
     (filter bar)
     (map baz)
     ,,,)


;; with transducers: seq processed in a single pass
(sequence (comp
           (map foo)
           (filter bar)
           (map baz))
          my-seq)
```

Comment: Relevant and interesting article: https://stuartsierra.com/2015/04/26/clojure-donts-concat

Comment: Thanks Arne! With your answer and a little help from Stuart Sierra finally all pieces begin to fit together. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Arne had a good answer (and, in fact, I'd never noticed `cat` before!).  If you want a simpler solution, you can use the `glue` function [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#gluing-together-like-collections):

---

## Gluing Together Like Collections

The concat function can sometimes have rather surprising results:

```
(concat {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3} )
;=>   ( [:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3] )
```

In this example, the user probably meant to merge the 3 maps into one. Instead, the three maps were mysteriously converted into length-2 vectors, which were then nested inside another sequence.

The conj function can also surprise the user:

```
(conj [1 2] [3 4] )
;=>   [1 2  [3 4] ]
```

Here the user probably wanted to get `[1 2 3 4]` back, but instead got a nested vector by mistake.

Instead of having to wonder if the items to be combined will be merged, nested, or converted into another data type, we provide the glue function to always combine like collections together into a result collection of the same type:

```
; Glue together like collections:
(is (= (glue [ 1 2] '(3 4) [ 5 6] )       [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]  ))   ; all sequential (vectors & lists)
(is (= (glue {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3} )       {:a 1 :c 3 :b 2} ))   ; all maps
(is (= (glue #{1 2} #{3 4} #{6 5} )      #{ 1 2 6 5 3 4 }  ))   ; all sets
(is (= (glue "I" " like " \a " nap!" )   "I like a nap!"   ))   ; all text (strings & chars)

; If you want to convert to a sorted set or map, just put an empty one first:
(is (= (glue (sorted-map) {:a 1} {:b 2} {:c 3})   {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} ))
(is (= (glue (sorted-set) #{1 2} #{3 4} #{6 5})  #{ 1 2 3 4 5 6  } ))
```

An Exception will be thrown if the collections to be 'glued' are not all of the same type. The allowable input types are:

- all sequential: any mix of lists & vectors (vector result)
- all maps (sorted or not)
- all sets (sorted or not)
- all text: any mix of strings & characters (string result)

---

I put `glue` into your code instead of `concat` and still got a StackOverflowError. So, I also replaced the lazy `filter` and `remove` with eager versions `keep-if` and `drop-if` to get this result:

```
(defn qsort [list]
  (loop [[current & todo :as all] [list] sorted []]
    (cond
      (nil? current) sorted

      (or (nil? (seq current)) (= (count current) 1))
          (recur todo (glue sorted current))

      :else (let [[pivot & rest] current
                  pred #(> (compare pivot %) 0)
                  lt   (keep-if pred rest)
                  gte  (drop-if pred rest)
                  work (list* lt [pivot] gte todo)]
              (recur work sorted)))))

(defn tlfnum [] (str/join (repeatedly 10 #(rand-int 10))))
(defn tlfbook [n] (repeatedly n #(tlfnum)))
(def result
  (time (count (qsort (tlfbook 10000)))))

-------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.8.0    Java 1.8.0_111
-------------------------------------
"Elapsed time: 1377.321118 msecs"
result => 10000
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! Indeed, tupelo looks like an interesting library. But my question was more about "why" than about "how"