# Making a list "unlazy" in clojure

Tags: clojure, evaluation, lazy-evaluation

I recently noticed that there was a very clear implementation of insertion sort here :

[Insertion sort in clojure throws StackOverFlow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814892/insertion-sort-in-clojure-throws-stackoverflow-error)

- which suffers from a memory overflow, due to the fact that concat lazily joins lists.  I was wondering :

What strategies can we apply to "de-lazying" a list when we want better performance on large collections ?

Comment: Hmm... After some more googling, its clear that the simple answer to this question is by using the "doall" function to wrap the collection.  However, I assume there might be some gotchas here which might be useful to know about.

Answer (score 6):

[doall](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall) is certainly fine for forcing lazy evaluation.

Another useful thing to remember is that [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) is non-lazy. This can therefore be very useful in large computations for ensuring that intermediate results get evaluated and reduced to a single output value before the computation proceeds.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvote. `doall` will do the job and a `reduce` accumulating into a vector also provides a solution, which shouldn't be dismissed immediatelly. The result has fast random access which might be interesting for certain applications. (That said: a `vec` around the resulting sequence would also give the same result.)

Comment: I agree do all would work... In fact, it did work I tried it just after posting this question, regarding the other referenced post.   Please comment.