# Is there a Clojure function which takes a map and returns a sequence of alternating keys and values?

Tags: clojure, destructuring

Given a map `{:a 1 :b [2,3]}`, is there a built-in function which would return the sequence `(:a 1 :b [2,3])`.

The use case is applying an options map to a function which does map-destructured binding on the remainder of an argument list. [Here's an example of this in core.cache](https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/blob/10cc84973a7b97ada8fb56e9859ce101a477bde5/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/cache.clj#L545-564). Here's a contrived example to illustrate:

```
(defn make-car [& {:as options}] (assoc options :car true))
(make-car :color "red" :speed "fast")
; => {:car true, :speed "fast", :color "red"}
```

Now if we want to manage the options separately and `apply` them to the function, we have a problem:

```
(def options {:color "red" :speed "fast"})
(apply make-car options)
; => {:car true, [:speed "fast"] [:color "red"]}
```

...because of course the `seq` of a map is a sequence of its key-value pairs. This is the best I've come up with:

```
(apply make-car (interleave (keys options) (vals options)))
; => {:car true, :speed "fast", :color "red"}
```

This is pretty awful. I know I could just make my own function to do this, but I'm surprised I haven't found something built-in. If there isn't something built-in, then I'd probably want to avoid destructuring argument lists like this in library code.

Comment: I believe you're looking for this: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.test-is/flatten-map

Apparently it didn't make it into core. I agree that this is a bit weird though. PS: `(comp (partial apply concat) seq)` imho looks a bit better than interleave, though a builtin would of course have been better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
(reduce concat {:a 1 :b [2,3]})
(:a 1 :b [2 3])
```

**Update** based on the comment from amalloy.
Apply is more efficient (at least in 1.4), and achieves the same result!

```
(apply concat {:a 1 :b [2,3]})
(:a 1 :b [2 3])
```

Comment: `(reduce concat)` is very dangerous for large sequences, and needlessly inefficient for small ones. Use `(apply concat)` instead.

Comment: What makes it dangerous for large sequences?

Comment: Hey, thanks @amalloy. I ran some tests and you are definitely right about apply being faster. Correcting the answer, with a note.

Comment: As far as being dangerous--I suppose it might stack overflow, or just be dangerously slow.

Comment: Try `(first (f concat (repeat 1e5 [1])))`, substituting `apply` and `reduce` for `f`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow for a description of similar code with the same problem.