# StackOverflow when using Iterate in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a function in Clojure that finds the first x prime numbers.
I wrote these functions:

```
(defn isprime? [n]
  (if (empty? (filter #(= 0 (mod n  %)) (range 2 n)))
    n
    0)
  )

(defn listprimes [nums]
    (if (first nums)
      (cons (isprime? (first nums)) (listprimes (rest nums)))
      [])
  )
```

The first one checks if a given number is prime or not, retruns it if it is or 0 id it isn't. The second gets a vector of numbers and activates the first function on each element. So, if my input to `listprimes` is [1 2 3 4 5 6] the output will be [1 2 3 0 5 0].

I was planning to use `filter` in the following way (for any x):

`(take x (filter #(== 0 %) (listprimes(iterate inc 0)))`

But I get a StackOverflow.. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive function causing a stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946764/recursive-function-causing-a-stack-overflow)

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.. :/

Comment: @bereal Not the same. This one fails for lack of laziness. The question you refer to fails for too much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listprimes` is recursive and not lazy. Supplying it with the endless `(iterate inc 0)` is bound to overflow the stack, as each number nests another function call.

A lazy version of `listprimes` is ...

```
(defn listprimes [nums]
  (map isprime? nums))
```

Then, for example,

```
(take 20 (filter #(== 0 %) (listprimes (iterate inc 0))))
```

yields ...

```
;(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

... not informative, but at least it terminates.

---

By the way,

`isprime?` does too much for its name. Peel it of the `if` form, leaving  ...

```
(defn isprime? [n]
  (empty? (filter #(= 0 (mod n  %)) (range 2 n))))
```

For example,

```
(filter isprime? (range 2 20))
;(2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19)
```

Then the sort of result you want is better expressed thus:

```
(take 20 (remove isprime? (iterate inc 0)))
;(4 6 8 9 10 12 14 15 16 18 20 21 22 24 25 26 27 28 30 32)
```

Comment: Nope.. changes nothing.

Comment: @shakedzy Are you still trying to use your `listprimes` function?  I believe Thumbnail is arguing that you shouldn't.  Just use `filter` to get the list of primes.  Doing so does change the behavior for me.  You're version SOs on `(range 2 10000)`, while I have no issues with this version.  And it does get rid of the recursion introduced is `listprimes`.  If you're keen on having similar output of `listprimes`, you could redefine it to be: `(defn listprimes [nums] (map #(if (isprime? %) % 0) nums))` with this version of `isprime?`.