# What's wrong with this clojure prime seq?

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I can't figure out why this definition of a lazy primes sequence would cause non-termination.  The stack-trace I get isn't very helpful (my one complaint about clojure is obtuse stack-traces).

```
(declare naturals is-prime? primes)

(defn naturals
  ([] (naturals 1))
  ([n] (lazy-seq (cons n (naturals (inc n))))))

(defn is-prime? [n]
  (not-any? #(zero? (rem n %))
                (take-while #(> n (* % %)) (primes))))

(defn primes
  ([] (lazy-seq (cons 2 (primes 3))))
  ([n] (let [m (first (filter is-prime? (naturals n)))]
         (lazy-seq (cons m (primes (+ 2 m)))))))

(take 10 (primes)) ; this results in a stack overflow error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start executing `primes`, and we'll magically realise one `seq` just to be clear. I'll ignore `naturals` because it's correctly lazy:

```
 > (magically-realise-seq (primes))
=> (magically-realise-seq (lazy-seq (cons 2 (primes 3))))
=> (cons 2 (primes 3))
=> (cons 2 (let [m (first (filter is-prime? (naturals 3)))]
             (lazy-seq (cons m (primes (+ 2 3))))))
=> (cons 2 (let [m (first (filter
                            (fn [n]
                              (not-any? #(zero? (rem n %))
                                            (take-while #(> n (* % %)) (primes))))) 
                            (naturals 3)))]
             (lazy-seq (cons m (primes (+ 2 3))))))
```

I've substituted `is-prime?` in as a `fn` at the end there—you can see that `primes` will get called again, and realised at least once as `take-while` pulls out elements. This will then cause the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that to know to calculate the "primes" function you are using the "is-prime?" function, and then to calculate the "is-prime?" function you are using "(primes)", hence the stack over flow.

So to calculate the "(primes 3)", you are need calculate the "(first (filter is-prime? (naturals 3)))", which is going to call "(is-prime? 1)", which is calling "(primes)", which in turns calls "(primes 3)". In other words you are doing:

```
user=> (declare a b)
#'user/b
user=> (defn a [] (b))
#'user/a
user=> (defn b [] (a))
#'user/b
user=> (a)
StackOverflowError   user/b (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

To see how to generate prime numbers: [Fast Prime Number Generation in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960980/fast-prime-number-generation-in-clojure)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you're trying to use (primes) before it's already constructed.

Changing `is-prime?` like that fixes the problem:

```
(defn is-prime? [n]
     (not-any? #(zero? (rem n %))
               (take-while #(>= n (* % %)) (next (naturals)))))
```

(Note, that I've changed `>` with `>=`, otherwise it gives that 4 is prime.  It still says that 1 is prime, which isn't true and may cause problems if you use `is-prime?` elsewhere.