# Python prime number list wrong?

Tags: python, list, primes

I've tried with several different methods to get the 10001 prime number.

```
def isPrime(value):
  if ((2**value)-2)%value==0:
    return True

def nthPrime(n):
  count = 0
  value = 1
  while count < n:
    value += 1
    if isPrime(value):
      count += 1
  return value
```

When 10001 is the argument this returns 103903.  When I'm expecting 104743.

I've tried:

```
primes = []
for i in range(2,105000):
  if ((2**i) - 2) % i == 0:
    primes.append(i)

print primes[10001] ---> 103903
```

Comment: What does your `isPrime` function answer for numbers: 1105, 1729, 2465 ? You'd know at plain sight that 1105 and 2465 are *not* prime... (Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)

Comment: Pseudo-prime numbers eh, I vaguely remember coming across this before but, this has given it some context.  Good  stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your prime sieve is wrong.  Try using an isPrime function that takes that number mod each lesser prime.  If any of these are 0 then the number is composite (not prime).  To the best of my knowledge there is no single comparison that will tell you if a number is prime, as your isPrime function assumes.

Answer (score 2):

Is this for Project Euler? It does seem familiar to me.

Your isPrime function is wrong, like TEOUltimus said, there is no one way to tell if a number is prime.

[Simple Prime Generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-python)

This pretty much answers your question i guess.

Answer (score 2):

**You can make a function to generate primes, this might be slow but it will work.**

Here's my function to do so :

```
def PrimesSieve(limit):
    np=set()
    p=[2]
    for i in xrange(1,limit+1,2):
            if i == 1: continue
            if {i} & np: continue
            beg=2 if i % 2 == 0 else 0
            for j in xrange(beg,int(limit)+1,i):
                    np.add(j)
            p.append(i)
    return p
```

Comment: I've never used the sieve method.  After seeing your implementation it became much clearer.  You populate an array of factors by stepping through a range incrementing by the integer, if the integer is in the factors array its not a prime if it isn't it is.

Comment: Also, I went and wrote a sieve using the description I gave above after I got the gist.  Only, I started the outer loop at 2 and have the inner loop start at 0.  I got correct results, I'm thinking this is a slight performance improvement?

Comment: A small optimization for your code.  You can use logical operators on `sets()`.  `if i in np: continue` can be changed to `if {i} & np: continue`

Comment: Thank you for optimization :)

Comment: Is it faster to use `if {i} & np` or `if i in np`?

Comment: I timed those out and I was getting a slight improvement with `if {i} & np` for finding all primes > 1 million.  For finding all primes < 1 million `if i in np` was slightly faster.