# Prime number check Python

Tags: python, primes

I've written this very simple prime number check:

```
prime = int(input())
if prime % prime == 0 and prime % 2 != 0 and prime % 3 != 0 or prime == 2 or prime == 3:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

... which seems to work somehow, but i'm not certain if its the correct way, can someone please confirm?

Comment: I don't understand this part: `prime % prime == 0` ? Isn't that the modulo operator, which would return 0 every time

Comment: If this is homework you should tag it as such.

Comment: @Keyser You mean `0` every time?

Comment: prime & prime always returns 0, which is always equal to 0.

Comment: prime % 2 != 0 ?, so 2 and 3 are not primes

Comment: This code is not useful at all. You should not "hard code" these kinds of checks

Comment: If you were able to come up with such a short and fast algorithm to check for a prime number, then it means you have solved one of the hardest and most ancient problems in mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i'm not certain if its the correct way

It isn't. To give one counterexample, it thinks that `25` is a prime number. To make matters worse, there are infinitely many such counterexamples.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Testing_primality_and_integer_factorization) is worth of a read for various (correct) methods of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

As simple as it gets:

```
def isprime(n):
    """check if integer n is a prime"""
    # range starts with 2 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
    for x in xrange(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

For an impressive prime-number generator, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-pyt#)

Comment: I think this fails whith n = 1

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article on [primality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality) can help you design a better algorithm. There are many of them, but the basic ones are not that complicated.

- First, depart from the fact that a prime number must be a positive integer bigger than 1. This invariant implies that if n < 2 you could return false immediatelly. In your code, n=0 fails.
- In a naive approach, you can then move to check all divisors of n from 1 to n. If you just find two, then you know it's a prime.
- A more intuitive approach could be to conclude that every number is divisible by 1 and itself, and so, you could check for divisors only between 2 and n-1. And in the moment that you find a divisor of n, you can conclude n is not a prime.
- A improved approach recognizes that all even numbers are divisible by 2, and so, if n is not divisible by 2 then, from there on you can only check for odd divisors.
- Finally, you do not need to check for all the divisors up to n. It should suffice to check divisor up to the square root of n. If you haven't found a divisor when you reach that threshold, then you can conclude n is a prime.