# How to check for a prime number using python

Tags: python

I wrote the code below to check for prime numbers but when I run the code both the `if` and `else` statements execute the same output.

```
n = int(input("enter a number\n"))
for i in range(2, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        print(f"{n} is not prime")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is prime")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prime number check Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666154/prime-number-check-python)

Comment: pick a number in your head and walk through your algorithm. what will get printed if you enter 5? 6? 7?

Comment: [n := int(input("enter a number\n"))]
for i in range(1, n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(f"{n} is not prime")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is prime")

Answer (score 0):

[Sympy.isprime](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-isprime-method/) is probably the most efficient way unless you want to check various numbers. In that case, it's better to use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

If you do not want to use modules or semi-complicated algorithms, the following plain code works perfectly if you need to check just a few numbers smaller than 10**6.

```
def isprime(num):
    for n in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1): 
        if num%n==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that your loop prints out *something* on every iteration. You can't do that if you only want to print that `n` is prime when you're sure it is. You can only be sure of that when your whole loop completes.

This is easiest in a function, where you can `return` whenever you have a firm answer:

```
def prime_check(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True             # this only runs after the whole loop ends


n = int(input("enter a number\n"))
if prime_check(n):
    print(f"{n} is prime")
else:
    print(f"{n} is not prime")
```

If you want to keep the check inline, rather than using a function, you can do that too, with some clever use of `break` and the `else` clause *attached to the loop*, rather than the `if`. Such a clause only runs if the loop exits normally, not if it's exited early by a `break` statement. This can be a bit confusing, which is why I put it second, after the `return` version that is a lot more clear.

```
n = int(input("enter a number\n"))
for i in range(2, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        print(f"{n} is not prime")
        break
else:                       # the else is attached to the for loop now, not the if
    print(f"{n} is prime")  # this line is only runs if no break happened in the loop
```