# Python challenge: distinct combination of prime numbers in a given range

Tags: python, primes

Consider this challenge:

> Given two numbers `A` and `B`, in how many ways you can select `B` distinct primes, where each of the primes should be less than or equal to `A` (`<= A`). Since the number can be large, provide your answer mod 65537.

For example

If `A = 7` and `B = 2`, then:
All primes `<= A` are `{2, 3, 5, 7}`, and the answer will be `6`: `{2, 3} {2, 5} {2, 7} {3, 5} {3, 7} {5, 7}`

I have created this solution:

```
from math import factorial
from math import fmod 

def nPk(n,k):
    return int( factorial(n)/factorial(n- k))  

def is_prime(a):
    for i in range(2,a):
        if a % i ==0:
            return False
    return True

def distinct_primes(A):
    primes = []
    for i in range(2,A):
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
    return len(primes)

def fct(A, B):
    return nPk(distinct_primes(A),B)

#print fct(59,5)% 65537
print fmod(fct(69,8), 65537)
```

But, I am not getting the right answer! What am I missing here?

Comment: BTW you could speed the search for primes up quite significantly if you used known `primes` in search for `is_prime`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/568618/223424).

Comment: @9000 you mean [*this answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10733621/849891)? It's a tweak of the code you linked to, and is 1.3x faster and takes *O(sqrt(n/log n))* extra space instead of *O(n)*, to produce *n* primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionut is correct about the inclusive issue!
In addition to that, you should change nPk definition to:

```
def nPk(n,k):
    return int( factorial(n)/(factorial(n- k) * factorial(k)))
```

Comment: the edited function fails in some cases like for n = 334 and k = 25 I can't see why, could you please have another look

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(2,A):
```

should be

```
for i in range(2, A+1):
```

because you have to consider all primes **<=** A.

Answer (score 0):

alfasin is correct; the issue is that the order in which you choose the primes doesn't matter. Thus you want to use a combination rather than a permutation.