# Generator function for prime numbers

Tags: python, generator, primes

I'm trying to write a generator function for printing prime numbers as follows

```
 def getPrimes(n):
    prime=True
    i=2
    while(i<n):
        for a in range(2,i):
            if(i%a==0):
                prime=False
                break
        if(prime):    
            yield i
```

However I'm not getting the desired results
p=getPrimes(100) should give me a generator function that will iterate primes from 2 through 100 but the result I'm getting is [2,3]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python/10733621#10733621 for a general generator which improves on the one by David Eppstein (/ Alex Martelli ?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reset `prime` to `True` as the first statement inside the while block, not before it.  As it is, once you hit a single composite number, `prime` will never be true again, so you'll never yield any more numbers.

Answer (score 12):

### Sieve of Eratosthenes: Most efficient prime generator algorithm

#### Taken from here:

[Simple Prime Generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-python/568618#568618) - an answer by Eli Bendersky.

[image]

It marks off all the multiples of `2`, `3`, `5`, `7` and `11`. The rest are all prime numbers.

```
def genprimes(limit): # derived from 
                      # Code by David Eppstein, UC Irvine, 28 Feb 2002
    D = {}            # http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119/
    q = 2

    while q <= limit:
        if q not in D:
            yield q
            D[q * q] = [q]
        else:
            for p in D[q]:
                D.setdefault(p + q, []).append(p)
            del D[q]
        q += 1

p = genprimes(100)
prms = [i for i in p]

print prms
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Very interesting.

Comment: It's not the most efficient, but it's good.

Comment: At least [cite your source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/568618/100297) for the code (or did you use the [Python cookbook recipe directly perhaps](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119/)); removing the comments to claim this as your own is not all that nice. You left an error in the code, btw.

Comment: Please review [how to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). You need to be more precise in your credit.

Comment: Notice how the code in the other answer includes a comment at the top where it was taken from? It includes a clear URL, and the author of the code. Also note that `D[q * q]` is assigned to, not `D[q * 2]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of errors, see the comments:

```
def getPrimes(n):
    i = 2
    while i < n :
        prime = True # reset the `prime` variable before the inner loop
        for a in xrange(2, i):
            if i%a == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime:    
            yield i
        i += 1 # don't forget to advance `i`
```

Now for a better implementation that handles correctly the edge cases, performs a great deal less iterations and generates a sequence of the prime numbers less than the value of the `n` parameter:

```
def getPrimes(n):
    if n <= 2:
        raise StopIteration
    yield 2
    for i in xrange(3, n, 2):
        for x in xrange(3, int(i**0.5)+2, 2):
            if not i % x:
                break
        else:
            yield i
```

Either way, the code works as expected:

```
[x for x in getPrimes(20)]
=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def isprime(n):
    for i in range(2 ,int((n**0.5))+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def getPrimes(n):
    yield 2
    i = 1
    while i <= n-2:
        i += 2
        if isprime(i):
            yield i
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Istvan Chung answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706903/1405065), your issue comes from the fact that you don't ever reset your `prime` flag. However, rather than fixing that issue directly, I suggest an alternative solution.

Rather than using a flag variable to detect when you've made it all the way through the loop without hitting a `break`, use an `else` block after the loop:

```
def getPrimes(n):
    i = 2
    while i < n :
        for a in range(2, i):
            if i % a == 0:
                break
        else:    
            yield i
```

The `else` block will be run if the loop completes, rather than being stopped early by a `break` statement.

You could probably improve this further by only testing prime divisors, rather than all integers less than `i`. Here's a way to do that with recursion (an alternative is to keep a list of the previously computed primes, but that may require a lot of storage space if `n` is very large):

```
def getPrimes(n):
    yield 2
    i = 3
    while i < n:
        for a in getPrimes(int(math.sqrt(i))+1):
            if i % a == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield i
        i += 2
```

Comment: in `for a in getPrimes(int(math.sqrt(i))+1):` *`getPrimes` will be calculated for every `i`*.  Instead, you can keep the list of previous primes _only_ up to the _sqrt_ of `n`, and use *it* to test `i`s above the sqrt.

Comment: I didnt know you could use an else on loop statements too