# Python Prime Number Generator

Tags: python

The code prints every non-prime number twice but the prime-numbers only once.
However, I only want the prime-numbers to be printed out.
I know there are way better Solutions for a prime-number-generator but I really want to know where the mistake in this code is.

```
prime_numbers = []

def prime_gen(upper_limit):
    for i in range(2, upper_limit):
        for j in range(2, upper_limit):
            if i % j == 0 and i % j != 1 and i % j != j and i:
                prime_numbers.append(i)
prime_gen(20)
print(prime_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop `j` at `i`, not the upper limit. No point looking for divisors of `i` that are larger than `i` - there aren't any. And `i` itself shouldn't be tested, as it always divides itself.

And a number isn't prime because it's divisible by another but because it isn't. So test *all* possible divisors and only at the end, if none was found, only then add `i` to the prime number list.

```
prime_numbers = []

def prime_gen(upper_limit):
    for i in range(2, upper_limit):
        for j in range(2, i):             # <== only look for divisors less than i
            if i % j == 0:                # <== STOP if you found a divisor
                break
        else:                             # <== Add only if no divisor was found
            prime_numbers.append(i)
prime_gen(20)
print(prime_numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 prime_numbers = [2] # we know two is prime
 def prime_gen(upper_limit):
    # start at 3 and use a step of 2
    for i in range(3, upper_limit, 2):
        # loop from 2 to i
        for j in range(2, i):
            # if i was divisible by any j we will break the loop
            # as i is not prime
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            # if we get here we completed our inner loop
            # which means no i % j was equal to 0
            prime_numbers.append(i)
```

You need the inner loop to go from 2 to i, you don't want numbers that satisfy  `if i % j == 0` as those are not prime. Your last `and i` is also always going to be True, any number that is not `0` will be True so the test is redundant. You can also start at 3 and use a step of 2, all  even numbers cannot be prime.

You can also replace the `if/else` with [any:](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) which will lazily evaluate and break if we find any `i % j` that equals 0.

```
prime_numbers = [2]

def prime_gen(upper_limit):
    for i in range(3, upper_limit, 2):
        if not any(i % j == 0 for j in range(2, i)):
            prime_numbers.append(i)
```

Comment: @DavidBeck, no worries, you're welcome. If you do actually want an efficient way to generate primes, use a sieve of Eratosthenes http://stackoverflow.com/a/23423821/2141635

Answer (score 0):

First one is not optimised, while the second one is slightly more optimised. Of course, "[Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706914/4751300)" is the best. This functions produce the prime numbers in sequence, but not having an upper limit.

Simple and not optimised:

```
def simple_prime_list(num):
    list_of_prime = (2, )
    current_num = 2
    is_prime = True
    while len(list_of_prime) != num:
        current_num += 1
        for i in list_of_prime:
            if current_num % i == 0:
                is_prime = False
        if is_prime == True:
            list_of_prime += (current_num,)
        #To reset the status
        is_prime = True
    return list_of_prime
```

Slightly optimised by not checking all even number and `break` out of the for loop when the number is not a prime:

```
def prime_list(num):
    list_of_prime = (2, )
    current_num = 2
    is_prime = True
    while len(list_of_prime) != num:
        current_num += 1
        if current_num % 2 != 0:
            for i in list_of_prime:
                if current_num % i == 0:
                    is_prime = False
                    break
            if is_prime == True:
                list_of_prime += (current_num, )
        #To reset the status
        is_prime = True
    return list_of_prime
```

Try measuring the 2 different runtime:

```
import time
def measureTime(fn):
    start = time.clock()
    fn()
    end = time.clock()
    #return value in millisecond
    return (end - start)*1000

print('Simple Prime List:', measureTime(lambda: simple_prime_list(1000)), 'ms')
print('Optimised Prime List:', measureTime(lambda: prime_list(1000)), 'ms')
```

Output:

> Simple Prime List: 775.798 ms
>
> Optimised Prime List: 69.48299999999996 ms

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for generator you should use **yield** instead of **return**, here is my answer for a infinite primes generator:

```
def primes_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        for x in range(2, n): 
            if n % x == 0:
                #not prime
                break
        else: 
            #prime
            yield n #<- yield instead of return to create a generator
        n+=1
```

if you need an upper limit you can use it like:

```
def primes_generator(upper_limit):
    for n in range(2, upper_limit):
        for x in range(2, n): 
            if n % x == 0: break
        else: 
            yield n
```

then you can use it like:

```
primes = primes_generator()
for prime in primes:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple python console prime number generator

```
global num,primes
num = 1
primes=[]
gen = raw_input("enter the number of primes to generate: ")


while len(primes)<int(gen)+1:
    if num > 0:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                num+=1
                break
    else:
        print(primes)
            primes.append(num)
            num+=1
print "Primes generated : ",len(primes)-1
```