# the continue in for else in python

Tags: python

```
for ele in eles:
   for i in xrange(10):
       try:
            #do something
           break
        except:
            continue
   else:
       if some condition:
           continue
       #do something
```

consider above code, i know the `break` will break the inner for loop, the first `continue` will continue inner for loop, what about the second `continue`? which for loop will it continue?

Comment: Why not try an example and see? Think about this, though - is the inner `for` loop still running when the `else` block is reached?

Comment: Insert a `print()` and see which one `continue`s.

Comment: @musefan: the `else` is executed if the `for` loop completed without being interrupted. E.g. if no `break` statement was executed. Wonderfully useful when [calculating prime numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/568684) for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ahhh, that is quite interesting... though perhaps not the best choice of keyword using `else`. Also, that prime number example function, would you even need the `else`? Surely it would work just returning true, as it would only be hit if it didn't return false already

Comment: @musefan: the poor choice of the `else` keyword has been cited a few days ago on the python-dev mailing list. :)

Comment: @musefan: yes, the feature is wonderful, the exact word used not so much.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini link?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: [here you are](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-April/032995.html): *in the second case, the for-loop, "else" is not the best choice of keyword* (it was actually posted on python-ideas, not python-dev).

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini much obliged, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest `continue` takes effect on the outer `for` loop, as demonstrated by the following example:

```
>>> for x in [1, 2, 3]:
...     for y in [4, 5, 6]:
...         print('x =', x, 'y =', y)
...     else:
...         continue
...     print('here')
... 
x = 1 y = 4
x = 1 y = 5
x = 1 y = 6
x = 2 y = 4
x = 2 y = 5
x = 2 y = 6
x = 3 y = 4
x = 3 y = 5
x = 3 y = 6
```

Note that "here" gets never printed.

Also, note that the inner for loop cannot be continued in any way: the `else` block is executed when the iterator is exhausted (in my example: when all the `y`s in `[4, 5, 6]` have been printed) and when no `break` statements have been executed. Because the iterator has been exhausted, there are no ways to make it produce more values.