# Different output in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I made a simple program to generate prime numbers but It shows 10 as a prime number. In debugging the for loop incremented i from 2 to 4 in single step when number went from 9 to 10.

```
for i in range (2, int( number / 2) + 1):
    if number % i == 0:
        number += 1 
        i = 2
    yield number
    number += 1`
```

Comment: k, keep us posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Prime Generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-python)

Comment: you forgot to break out of the for-loop