# How to explain this “lambda in filter changes the result when calculating primes"

Tags: python, lambda, filter

When I change to use lambda in filter(), the result of code changes. Why?

Code to calculate primes. You can copy the code to run it directly.

```py
def get_odd_iter():
    oddNum = 1
    while True:
        oddNum = oddNum + 2
        yield oddNum

def not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x: x%n>0


def prime_iter():
    yield 2
    odd_iter = get_odd_iter()

    while True: 
        odd = next(odd_iter)
        yield odd
        # odd_iter = filter(not_divisible(odd), odd_iter)  # <--(1)
        odd_iter = filter((lambda x: x%odd>0) , odd_iter)  # <--(2)


p = prime_iter()

print(next(p))
print(next(p))
print(next(p))
print(next(p))
print(next(p))
print(next(p))
```

When I use (1), everything goes well.
When I change to (2), 9 will be in the result, which is actually not a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting `filter`s, and with the `lambda`, all of them are closures on `odd` in the calling scope, and they're all lazy; none of them produce values until requested. So when you reassign `odd` in the next run of the `while` loop, they *all* use the *new* value of `odd`, *not* the individual values of `odd` from when each `lambda`/`filter` wrapping was created.

Using the function, they each close on the `odd` in function scope, which never changes. To achieve a similar effect with `lambda`s, capture the present value of `odd` as a default argument:

```
    odd_iter = filter((lambda x, odd=odd: x%odd>0), odd_iter)
                                 ^^^^^^^ captured
```

which means that copy of the `lambda` is no longer referencing closure scope to find the updating value of `odd`, it just reads it once for the current value of `odd` and then uses it's own local, unchanging cached value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, very useful.
"none of them produce values until requested",
"requested" refers to "yield"?

Comment: @JeffreyHao: Roughly; `filter` is implemented in C and doesn't actually use the `yield` keyword, but close enough. Point is, none of them are produced until you actually iterate the result, and each result is only produced at the moment you reach it. So each `next` pulls a value, using the current value of `odd` for all `filter`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is because lambdas look up their arguments' names **at the time of calling**, not at the time of creation. The first variant works because you are **binding** the value of `odd` to the lambda in `not_divisible`. Consider changing

`odd_iter = filter(not_divisible(odd), odd_iter)`

to

`odd_iter = filter(not_divisible, odd_iter)`

just leaving the callable without arguments, and you will be getting similar **incorrect** results.

For the lambda to work, you must **explicitly set (bind) its 'hidden' argument**, like so:

`odd_iter = filter(lambda x,odd=odd: x%odd>0, odd_iter)`

This will produce correct results.

Also, consider a better solution to generate primes, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-generator-in-python) for instance.