# List of conditions

Tags: python

I wanted to make a list of conditions for if. I wanted to make a program that would find very high prime numbers. I don't want to write: number % 2 == 0 or - for every number that I divide with. If you know how to make a list of conditions or know how to easier get high prime numbers using yield please give me a hint.

```
def very_high_prime_numbers_generator():
    number = 0
    while True:
        number = yield
        if not (number % 2 == 0 or number % 3 == 0 or number % 7 == 0 or number % 5 == 0 or number % 11 == 0 or number % 17 == 0 or number % 19 == 0 or number % 13 == 0):
            print(number)

number_generator = very_high_prime_numbers_generator()

number_generator.send(None)

for i in range(1000,10000):
    number_generator.send(i)
```

Comment: "*I wanted to make a list of conditions for if.*" -- what does that mean?

Comment: "*I wanted to make a program that would find very high prime numbers.*" -- your current approach seems quite hard-coded. I think you will have to do a lot more research before you can tackle this problem.

Comment: Your algorithm will need some work, since it does seem to be generating some false primes. I suggest looking into some existing [primality testing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) and [prime generation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_of_primes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested loop or `any` or `all` to test the divisibility of the number against all those values:

```
if not any(number % k == 0 for k in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)):
    print(number)
```

Of course, this still tests only *those* values, which will not be enough for "very high prime numbers". Instead, you could keep track of the prime number generated so far an test against all of those:

```
def very_high_prime_numbers_generator():
    primes = []
    number = 2
    while True:
        if not any(number % p == 0 for p in primes):
            yield number
            primes.append(number)
        number += 1

number_generator = very_high_prime_numbers_generator()
for _ in range(100):
    print(next(number_generator))
```

(This could be further enhanced by stopping once `k**2 > number`, e.g. using `itertools.takewhile`, and only testing odd numbers above 2.)

Also note that your "generator" was rather odd. By using `send` to set the value of `number` and then printing inside the function, your "generator" behaved rather like a regular "check if this number is prime" function than a proper generator. The above also fixes that.

Comment: @maksymilian If you feel like this solved your problem, please consider "accepting" the answer (or another if those worked better) to mark the question as being resolved.

Comment: Done ! Sorry for doing it so late I'm new to programming and things like stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're trying to do although as others have pointed out it's far from efficient.

```
def find_prime(number, previous_primes):
    for value in previous_primes:
        if number % value == 0:
            return False
    return True


known_primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
for i in range(8, 1000):
    is_prime = find_prime(i, known_primes)
    if is_prime:
        known_primes.append(i)
```

Comment: yeah I know its  bad but I was tasked with making a program that would generate high prime numbers but it has to be done with yield. Thanks for answering but I wanted to understand better how to use yield. Can you tell me where you would use yield in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise having a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567222/simple-prime-number-generator-in-python).

a possible solution (yet not that efficient) for printing primes might be as described by Eli Bendersky, in the above link:

```
import math

def main():
    count = 3
    
    while True:
        isprime = True
        
        for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count) + 1)):
            if count % x == 0: 
                isprime = False
                break
        
        if isprime:
            print count
        
        count += 1
```